# Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?

Tags: shell, find

I'm trying to use `find` to `echo 0` into some files, but apparently this only works with `sh -c`:

```
find /proc/sys/net/ipv6 -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'echo 0 > {}' \;
```

But using `sh -c` with `find -exec` makes me feel very uneasy because I suspect quoting problems. I fiddled a bit with it and apparently my suspicions were justified:

- My test setup:

  ```
  martin@dogmeat ~ % cd findtest 
  martin@dogmeat ~/findtest % echo one > file\ with\ spaces
  martin@dogmeat ~/findtest % echo two > file\ with\ \'single\ quotes\'
  martin@dogmeat ~/findtest % echo three > file\ with\ \"double\ quotes\"
  martin@dogmeat ~/findtest % ll
  insgesamt 12K
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 martin martin 6 Sep 17 12:01 file with "double quotes"
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 martin martin 4 Sep 17 12:01 file with 'single quotes'
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 martin martin 4 Sep 17 12:01 file with spaces
  ```
- Using `find -exec` without `sh -c` seems to work without problems - no quoting necessary here:

  ```
  martin@dogmeat ~ % find findtest -type f -exec cat {} \;
  one
  two
  three
  ```
- But when I'm using `sh -c` `{}` seems to require some kind of quoting:

  ```
  martin@dogmeat ~ % LANG=C find findtest -type f -exec sh -c 'cat {}' \;
  cat: findtest/file: No such file or directory
  cat: with: No such file or directory
  cat: spaces: No such file or directory
  cat: findtest/file: No such file or directory
  cat: with: No such file or directory
  cat: single quotes: No such file or directory
  cat: findtest/file: No such file or directory
  cat: with: No such file or directory
  cat: double quotes: No such file or directory
  ```
- Double quotes work as long as no file name contains double quotes:

  ```
  martin@dogmeat ~ % LANG=C find findtest -type f -exec sh -c 'cat "{}"' \;
  one
  two
  cat: findtest/file with double: No such file or directory
  cat: quotes: No such file or directory
  ```
- Single quotes work as long as no file name contains single quotes:

  ```
  martin@dogmeat ~ % LANG=C find findtest -type f -exec sh -c "cat '{}'" \;
  one
  cat: findtest/file with single: No such file or directory
  cat: quotes: No such file or directory
  three
  ```

I haven't found a solution that works in all cases. Is there something I'm overlooking, or is using `sh -c` in `find -exec` inherently unsafe?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Never embed `{}` in the shell code! That creates a command injection vulnerability. Note that for `cat "{}"`, it's not only about the `"` characters, `\`, `` ` ``, `$` are also a problem (consider for instance a file called `./$(reboot)/accept_ra`)¹.

<sup>(by the way, [some `find` implementations](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/find/#embedded) won't let you do that, and [POSIX leaves the behaviour *unspecified*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) when `{}` is not on its own in an argument to `find -exec`)</sup>

Here, you'd want to pass the file names as separate arguments to `sh` (not in the *code* argument), and the `sh` inline script (the *code* argument) to refer to them using positional parameters:

```
find . -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'echo 0 > "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Or, to avoid running one `sh` per file:

```
find . -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'for file do
  echo 0 > "$file"; done' sh {} +
```

The same applies to `xargs -I{}` or `zsh`'s `zargs -I{}`. Don't write:

```
<list.txt xargs -I{} sh -c 'cmd > {}'
```

Which would be a command injection vulnerability the same way as with `find` above, but:

```
<list.txt xargs sh -c 'for file do cmd > "$file"; done' sh
```

Which also has the benefit of avoiding running one `sh` per file and the error when `list.txt` doesn't contain any file.

With `zsh`'s `zargs`, you'd probably want to use a function rather than invoking `sh -c`:

```
do-it() cmd > $1
zargs -l1 ./*.txt -- do-it
```

Though you might as well use a `for` loop which in zsh can be very short:

```
for f (*.txt) cmd > $f
```

(failures of `cmd` except the last are not reported in the overall exit status though).

Note that in all the examples above the second `sh` above goes into the inline script's `$0`. You should use something relevant there (like `sh` or `find-sh`), not things like `_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string, as the value in `$0` is used for the shell's error messages:

```
$ find . -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'echo 0 > "$1"' inline-sh {} \;
inline-sh: ./accept_ra: Permission denied
```

GNU `parallel` works differently. With it, you do **not** want to use `sh -c` as [`parallel` does run a shell already and tries to replace `{}` with the argument quoted in the right syntax for the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/349483/22565).

```
<list.txt PARALLEL_SHELL=sh parallel 'cmd > {}'
```

---

<sup>¹ and depending on the `sh` implementation other characters whose encoding contains the encoding of those characters (in practice and with real-life character encoding, that's limited to bytes 0x5c and 0x60)</sup>

Comment: thats second `sh` seems to be some kind of placeholder, it works too if replaced by `_` for example - very useful if you want to call bash internals: `find /tmp -name 'fil*' -exec bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$1"' _ {} \;`. But does anybody know where this is documented?

Comment: @FlorianFida The first argument to the shell becomes `$0` (usually the name of the shell. You need to skip it in this scenario so it doesn't eat one of your normal positional arguments. The documentation for `-c` mentions this.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `find` not allowing that embedding?

Comment: @EtanReisner http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/#embedded

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice reference and +1 for the the `s/most/some/` in your answer.

Comment: +1, though I think using `sh` has its pluses and minuses. It gives better error messages, but isn't quite as clear to people as a placeholder vs `_`, which would be common and very intuitive.

Comment: @BroSlow, I couldn't agree less. It's not a placeholder. People need to know that's to set `$0`, and using `_` would deceive them into thinking it's a placeholder. And I can't see what's intuitive about `_` (it's even more cumbersome to type than `sh` on my British keyboard). If you want something shorter, use `.`. At least that suggests the `.` (`source`) command which would be slightly more appropriate for `$0`.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I guess it might be also worth noting that some programs might behave differently with a different `argv[0]`.

Comment: @phk, that's not `argv[0]` here, that's just the `$0` of the script. Sven's page is inaccurate here, a `r` won't make the shell enter a restricted mode as far as can tell and `zsh` won't change mode based on `$0`. `(exec -a rksh ksh -c 'cd /')` will run a restricted `ksh`, but not `ksh -c 'cd /' rksh`).

Comment: Stéphane, if you don't mind, is there an answer of yours that explains "why not embed {} in the shell code" ? I went though all your answers under [tag:find] but couldn't find one although I could swear I saw some stuff that you had written about this subject but can't recall if it was an answer, a comment in chat or on another site like compunix...  If/when you have the time, would you mind expanding on the "Never embed {}" part or do you think we should have a dedicated Q e.g. _"Security implications of using `find` with `-exec sh -c` and embedding `{}` in the shell code"_ ?

Comment: @don_crissti, there's [How to escape shell metacharacters automatically with \`find\` command?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/262072) and possibly others. A dedicated Q&A (for find and xargs) if it doesn't exist already would probably be a good idea, yes, though here it's a specific case of code injection so there's a broader range of things to avoid in general. See also [Do I need to encapsulate awk variables in quotes in order to sanitize them?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/113799)

Comment: Ah, I somehow missed the 1st one yesterday while skimming through the questions... The reason for asking was that (although I do know that  {} should never be embedded the shell code) I figured it would be best to have a post explaining "why not" so that we could link to it when seeing answers [like this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332455). I guess the answer in your 1st link will do. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. [What does "`_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string  is used for the shell's error messages" mean? Why does using `inline-sh` not work in the example, given that `inline-sh` is not `_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/448642/674)