# Replace cp function by rsync

Tags: find, rsync, nfs, cp, file-copy

I'm trying to replace my cp function by an rsync function
My cp function is the following

```
find /home/odroid/USBHD/Movies/ -iname "*.mkv" -mtime '-1' -exec cp -n {} /home/odroid/NASVD/Movies \;
```

do you guys have any idea how to do this(note the mtime can also be replaced by --ignore-existing

Comment: Please refer to the answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156259/47538) on how to use `rsync` with `find`.

Comment: Well.. Unfortunately I can not seem to get that to work.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to replace `cp -n` by `rsync` with the right options, or do you want to replace the whole command line? When you say “the mtime can also be replaced by --ignore-existing”, do you mean that copying all files but ignoring already-existing files would be ok, in which case, why isn't `rsync -a --ignore-existing /home/odroid/USBHD/Movies/ /home/odroid/NASVD/Movies/` ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /home/odroid/USBHD/Movies/ -iname "*.mkv" -mtime '-1' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} rsync -a --ignore-existing {} /home/odroid/NASVD/Movies/
```