# How to rename multiple files using find

Tags: shell, find

I want to rename multiple files (file1 ... fileN to file1_renamed ... fileN_renamed) using `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -exec mv filename='{}' $(basename $filename)_renamed ';'
```

But getting this error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘filename=./file1’: No such file or directory
```

This not working because filename is not interpreted as shell variable.

Comment: Why are you using ``basename``? Do you want `./2017/photos/holiday/dscn1234.jpg` to be renamed to `./dscn1234.jpg_renamed` in the top level directory?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The following is a direct fix of your approach:

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; mv "$x" "${x}_renamed"' \;
```

However, this is very expensive if you have lots of matching files, because you start a fresh shell (that executes a `mv`) for each match. And if you have funny characters in any file name, this will explode. A more efficient and secure approach is this:

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -print0 | xargs --null -I{} mv {} {}_renamed
```

It also has the benefit of working with strangely named files. If `find` supports it, this can be reduced to

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -exec mv {} {}_renamed \;
```

The `xargs` version is useful when not using `{}`, as in

```
find .... -print0 | xargs --null rm
```

Here `rm` gets called once (or with lots of files several times), but not for every file.

I removed the `basename` in you question, because it is probably wrong: you would move `foo/bar/file8` to `file8_renamed`, not `foo/bar/file8_renamed`.

**Edits** (as suggested in comments):

- Added shortened `find` without `xargs`
- Added security sticker

Comment: In the case the `x` is useless: `find . -type f -name 'file*' -exec mv {} "{}_renamed" \;` `xargs` version have the same efficiency like the first example/

Comment: The `x` is there only to *directly* fix the asker's approach.

Comment: (1) It is very dangerous to use `{}` directly in a shell (`sh -c "…"`) command — you should always pass it in as an argument.  (2) Not all versions of `find` support the `{}_renamed` construct.  (3) I don't understand your statement that `xargs` is useful for removing files (in contrast to renaming them).

Comment: @G-Man: The difference with `xargs` is not `mv` vs. `rm`, but use of `{}` vs. without. The former is similar to `mv file1 file1_renamed; mv file2 file2_renamed` while the latter is `rm file1 file2`.

Comment: @Costas: The first version starts `sh` and `mv` per file (unless `mv` is a shell builtin); the second version only starts one `mv` per file,

Comment: and if you then wanted to change the _renamed files back to their original names, how would you do that?

Comment: use -wholename instead of -name if you don't want to rename directories

Comment: the trick ${x%.*} remove file extension:  -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; mv $x ${x%.*}.xml'

Comment: I've successfully used `find . -type f -name '*foo*.xml' -exec rename foo bar {} \;` in zsh 5.9. Thanks for the good tips.

Answer (score 28):

After trying [the first answer](/questions/227662/how-to-rename-multiple-files-using-find/227671#227671) and toying with it a little I found that it can be done slightly shorter and less complex using `-execdir`:

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -execdir mv {} {}_renamed ';'
```

Looks like it should also do exactly what you need.

Comment: With `find` implementations that support `-execdir` and `{}` not as a whole, it's also the safest. You may want to add a `-i` to `mv` though (and `-T` if your `mv` supports it)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas even better, instead of relying on `mv` for a prompt, or in addition to it, you can (no doubt depending on whether your implementation of `find` supports it) also use `-okdir` which will output the command to be executed before executing it.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `-depth` is also a good idea if you are going to also touch directory names.

Comment: Argh, just found that `-execdir` does have one very annoying downside, `find` refuses to do anything if `PATH` contains any relative paths... https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-using-the-execdir-action-is-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path/1109378#1109378 `find: The relative path XXX is included in the PATH environment`

Comment: `$ find ./packages -type f -name '*.ddeb' -execdir mv {} {}.deb +` --> `find: Only one instance of {} is supported with -execdir ... +`; `find --version` --> `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0`.  info "(find) Multiple Files" says: `Only one '{}' is allowed within the command, and it must appear at the end, immediately before the '+'.`

Comment: Also to reduce complexity use perl tool with regexp replace 'rename' or more simple unix util 'rename' to do more complex renames without scripting/loops e.g. this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375310/74372

Answer (score 16):

Another approach is to use a `while read` loop over `find` output.  This allows access to each file name as a variable that can be manipulated without having to worry about additional cost / potential security issues of spawning a separate `sh -c` process using `find`'s `-exec` option.

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' |
    while IFS= read file_name; do
        mv "$file_name" "${file_name##*\/}_renamed"
    done
```

And if the shell being used supports the `-d` option to specify a `read` delimiter you can support strangely named files (e.g. with a newline) using the following:

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -d '' file_name; do
        mv "$file_name" "${file_name##*\/}_renamed"
    done
```

Comment: I had to search for files with specific prefix and drop them, this helped me a lot

`find . -name "prefix*" -maxdepth 1 |`
`while IFS= read file_name ; do; mv $file_name "${file_name/prefix//}"; done`

Answer (score 7):

I want to expand on [the first answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227662/how-to-rename-multiple-files-using-find/227671#227671) and note that this won't work to append to the filename since the `./` path prefix is present in the filename argument.

Modifying Thomas Erker answer, I find this one a more generic approach

```
find . -name PATTERN -printf "%f\0" | xargs --null -I{} mv {} "prefix {} suffix"
```

xargs options:

`--null` Indicates that each argument passed through `stdin` ends with a null character (`\0`). This way the filename can contain spaces, otherwise each word will be threated as a different parameter for the `mv` command.

`-I replace-str` Every ocurrence of `replace-str` will be replaced with the argument read from `stdin`. So, you may change it for other string if you need it so.

Comment: Why do the `pringf "%f\0"` instead of a `print0`?

Comment: @sim, because `-print0` will produce `./` prefixes if `PATTERN` contains shell metacharacters which get in the way when renaming to something that prefixes the original names. (e.g. rename `0 - foo.txt` to `00 - foo.txt`, `1 - bar.txt` to `01 - bar.txt` etc.)

Comment: an inefficient solution using sh and basename to add a prefix:  find . -name "job-info.json" -type f -execdir sh -c 'x="{}"; mv $x _.$(basename $x)' \;

Answer (score 7):

I was able to do something similar with the `for`, `find`, and `mv`.

```
for i in $(find . -name 'config.yml'); do mv $i $i.bak; done
```

This finds all the `config.yml` files and renames them to `config.yml.bak`

Comment: this has the advantage of being able to use variable expansion eg. ${i:r}. Nice answer.

Comment: Yeah, you can pretty much put any expression in the `for` and perform a bulk operation.

Comment: This solution doen't work if the file name include white space.

Comment: Flaws: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), [unquoted variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Answer (score 7):

I thought it will be nice if here will be provided the option to rename the file but to changing only the part of it's name. For example the file's extension.

What the point to change the file name if you only able to add something to it's name?

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec  sh -c 'x={}; mv "$x" $(echo $x | sed 's/\.txt/\.bat/g')' \;
```

Comment: Could be expensive, starting a new shell for each file.

Comment: this is crazy expensive but in my case with 117 files matched, ran in 1.9 sec and saved me a lot of tedium

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to replace the file extension in different folders use the following:

```
find . -name "*.OLD_EXTENSION" -exec sh -c 'file="{}"; mv  "$file" "${file%.OLD_EXTENSION}.NEW_EXTENSION"'  \;
```

Comment: Note that since you inject the found pathname directly into the code of the inline `sh -c` script, this will fail if the pathname contains double quotes. It may also allow for code injection by crafting directory names or filenames that break out of the double quote, contain a `;` character, and then any shell code, alternatively names that looks like variable expansions or command substitutions (e.g. `$(reboot)`).  See also [Is it possible to use \`find -exec sh -c\` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008)

Comment: this answer was most useful to me as most answers only provided code for adding strings to the filename, not removing substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove endings `*.sample`:

```shell
ls *.sample | cut -d"." -f-2 | xargs -I{} cp {}.sample {}
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is considered harmful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead