# How to rename multiple filenames using find/rename

Tags: shell, files, find, rename, samba

I have on a Samba server lots of files in directories/subdirectories containing special chars. The problem is that, the files (containing a special chars) are not visible when I try to view files using Windows.
So I wrote command (on the below) to change names of files with special characters, but putting back renamed files to dirs/subdirs doesn't work properly:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -v 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9 &](?=[^.]*\.)/_/g' '{}' \;
```

On the bottom I post current directory containing files to rename:

```
./dir 1/fil[special char]e3.jpg
./dir 1/another dir2/m[special char]r.file1.txt
./dir 1/another dir2/file[special char]2.doc
./dir 3/next dir4/dir 5/fi[special char]le5.xml
./file 4.zip
```

Expect - after using command described above (files in dirs/subdirs):

```
./dir 1/fil_e 3.jpg
./dir 1/another dir2/m_r_file1.txt
./dir 1/another dir2/file_2.doc
./dir 3/next dir4/dir 5/fi_le5.xml
./file 4.zip
```

reality - files in same folder  where I run command:

```
__dir 1_fil_e 3.jpg
__dir 1_another dir 2_m_r_file1.txt
__dir 1_another dir 2_file_2.doc
__dir 3_next dir4_dir 5_fi_le5.xml
__file 4.zip
```

and I have 2 questions:

1. how I can exclude pathname from filename?
2. how to put files in to directories?

Comment: Does your implementation of `find` have a `-execdir`?

Comment: On 99% - yes, samba runs on debian 8 so give me a moment to check

Comment: it works! ;) Thank you @steeldriver for help, problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have it, use the `-execdir` option for `find` instead of `-exec`.

- `-exec` runs the command from the root of the command with each path as an argument
- `-execdir` runs the command in the target directory with each filename as an argument

Thus,

```
find . -type f -execdir rename -v 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9 &](?=[^.]*\.)/_/g' '{}' \;
```

Please note, that since this answer was posted, the `rename` command referenced in the question and this answer has been overtaken by an alternative: `rename [options] expression replacement file…`. The `rename` shown here may be available on your system as `prename`. If not, you can [download](https://github.com/subogero/rename) and install it [using this recipe](https://superuser.com/a/1244641/332907).

Comment: Thank you too @roaima for explanation of the difference between -exec and -execdir, problem solved

Comment: Watch out, on some linux rename is a util-linux simple string replacement Usage: rename [options] expression replacement file..., on others rename is a perl tool (as in this example) with more complex expression replace https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_perl_oneliners/perl-rename-command.html

Comment: @gaoithe yes. However, when I wrote my question the perl version of `rename` was far more prevalent, and it matched the version the OP was using in their question

Comment: @roaima Your answer is a _very_ good one. The combination of -execdir and rename with find should be more widely known. I just added comment as the other rename is the default on many systems - unfortunately! - because the perl rename has proper expression replacement. Anyway, it's all good. Link to GNU rename reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html

Comment: @gaoithe thank you for the information. I've [amended the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/375310/revisions) to incorporate a similar suggestion