# Properly escaping output from pipe in xargs

Tags: shell, ls, quoting, xargs

Example:

```
% touch -- safe-name -name-with-dash-prefix "name with space" \
    'name-with-double-quote"' "name-with-single-quote'" \
    'name-with-backslash\'
```

`xargs` can't seem to handle double quotes:

```
% ls | xargs ls -l 
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
ls: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

If we use the `-0` option, it has trouble with name that has dash prefix:

```
% ls -- * | xargs -0 -- ls -l --
ls: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

This is before using other potentially problematic characters like newline, control character, etc.

Comment: Are you asking why `ls` doesn't work here? That's [normal behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls), and that's why you [never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Is that your question or is there something else?

Comment: @terdon the first `ls` is just to supply the names, one line per entry. This is not about parsing the output of `ls` (because in this case the first `ls` just gives the filenames, without any other modification except adding newline per entry). The second `ls` is to demonstrate how `xargs` feeds the names as arguments to the command. In this case, `xargs` somehow fails to pass the second `--` to `ls`.

Comment: Not sure how you got that error message upon `ls -- * | xargs -0 -- ls -l --`. I'd expect `ls` be passed just one big argument (possibly starting with a `-` but that wouldn't be a problem with `--`) since the input doesn't contain NULs and the error would be about that file with a long name and some newline characters not being found. What system and version of `ls`/`xargs` is that?

Comment: Like `ls: cannot access '-name-with-dash-prefix'$'\n''name with space'$'\n''name-with-backslash\'$'\n''name-with-double-quote"'$'\n''name-with-single-quote'\'''$'\n''safe-name'$'\n': No such file or directory`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm on Debian 8.0 Jessie, xargs 4.4.2, ls 8.23.

Comment: Can you reproduce it? Is it the first or second ls that outputs that error? What do you see if you run `ls -- * | strace -fe execve xargs -0 -- ls -l --` instead?

Comment: I can't. Apparently I copy-pasted the wrong error message. It should be something like you has (except with literal newlines and now surrounding single quotes). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) does give you an example for that:

```
ls | sed -e 's/"/"\\""/g' -e 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs -E '' printf '<%s>\n'
```

(with filenames being arbitrary sequences of *bytes* (other than `/` and NULL) and `sed`/`xargs` expecting *text*, you'd also need to fix the locale to C (where all non-NUL bytes would make valid characters) to make that reliable (except for `xargs` implementations that have a very low limit on the maximum length of an argument))

The `-E ''` is needed for some `xargs` implementations that without it, would understand a `_` argument to signify the end of input (where `echo a _ b | xargs` outputs `a` only for instance).

With GNU `xargs`, you can use:

```
ls | xargs -rd '\n' printf '<%s>\n'
```

(also adding `-r` (also a GNU extension) for the command not be run if the input is empty).

GNU `xargs` also has a `-0` that has been copied by a few other implementations, so:

```
ls | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 printf '<%s>\n'
```

is slightly more portable.

All of those assume the file names don't contain newline characters. If there may be filenames with newline characters, the output of `ls` is simply not post-processable. If you get:

```
a
b
```

That can be either both a `a` and `b` files or one file called `a<newline>b`, there's no way to tell.

GNU `ls` has a `--quoting-style=shell-always` which makes its output unambiguous and could be post-processable, but the quoting is not compatible with the quoting expected by `xargs`. `xargs` recognise `"..."`, `\x` and `'...'` forms of quoting. But both `"..."` and `'...'` are strong quotes and can't contain newline characters (only `\` can escape newline characters for `xargs`), so that's not compatible with sh quoting where only `'...'` are strong quotes (and can contain newline characters) but `\<newline>` is a line-continuation (is removed) instead of an escaped newline.

You can use the shell to parse that output and then output it in a format expected by `xargs`:

```
eval "files=($(ls --quoting-style=shell-always))"
[ "${#files[@]}" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" |
  xargs -0 printf '<%s>\n'
```

Or you can have the shell get the list of files and pass it NUL-delimited to `xargs`. For instance:

- with `zsh`:

  ```
  print -rNC1 -- *(N) | xargs -r0 printf '<%s>\n'
  ```
- with `ksh93`:

  ```
  (set -- ~(N)*; (($# == 0)) || printf '%s\0' "$@") |
    xargs -r0 printf '<%s>\n'
  ```
- with `fish`:

  ```
  begin set -l files *; string join0 -- $files; end |
    xargs -r0 printf '<%s>\n'
  ```
- with `bash`:

  ```
  (
    shopt -s nullglob
    set -- *
    (($# == 0)) || printf '%s\0' "$@"
  ) | xargs -r0 printf '<%s>\n'
  ```

**2023 Edit**. Since version 9.0 of GNU coreutils (September 2021), GNU `ls` now has a `--zero` option that can be used in conjunction with `xargs -r0`:

```
ls --zero | xargs -r0 printf '<%s>\n'
```

Comment: So to recap it's quite simple actually (I should've read the manpage once in a while :-) ): `xargs` interprets quotes (and backslash) except when given `-0` in which it only interprets NUL as record separator. Thanks for explanation about the different flavors of `xargs`.

Comment: Beside `/` and `NUL`, the link you quote also names `<new-line>` and `{}` as failures.

Comment: @Arrow, the example there is using `-I {}` and `$1`, `$2` as arguments to `xargs`, so if `{}` is found in `$1` and `$2` in that case, it's a problem. But not here as we're neither using `-I` nor passing variable arguments to `xargs`. Newline is covered in my answer. I should add `-E ''` though

Comment: The `sed` escape command misses single quotes as this fails: `echo "'" | sed -e 's/"/"\\""/g' -e 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo '{}'"`

Comment: @mgutt, **never** embed `{}` in the code argument of some interpreter as that results in command injection vulnerabilities. Here, you'd need an extra level of escaping for it to be used as shell code. Instead, use `xargs sh -c 'for arg do echo "$arg"; done' sh` which runs fewer `sh` invocations and passes the arguments as arguments to the inline script instead of embedding them in its code.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you. Found a good example for injection here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003457/318765 I can't use a loop, but it's safe now: https://superuser.com/a/1706699/129262

Comment: @mgutt, technically, the `+` argument of `date` is still some code in some language. That language is very limited, so you won't run commands with that, but an input like `%9999999999s` would still cause problem, making it a DoS vulnerability if not  an ACE. I would not use `xargs` for that. To timestamp input, you can use `perl` or `gawk` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks again. I updated my answer (its offtopic here, so please comment there if you want to).

Answer (score 4):

For `xargs` to understand the `-0` null-delimited input option, the sending party must also apply the null delimiter to the data that they are sending over.

Else there's no synchronization between the two.

One option is the `GNU find` command which can place such delimiters:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name . -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
```

Answer (score 3):

As you said, `xargs` doesn't like unmatched double quotes unless you use `-0` but `-0` only makes sense if you feed it null-terminated data. So, this fails:

```
$ echo * | xargs
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
name-with-backslash -name-with-dash-prefix
```

But this works:

```
$ printf '%s\0' -- * | xargs -0
-- name-with-backslash\ -name-with-dash-prefix name-with-double-quote" name-with-single-quote' name with space safe-name
```

In any case, your basic approach is not really the best way to do this. Instead of fiddling about with `xargs` and `ls` and whatnot, just use shell globs instead:

```
$ for f in *; do ls -l -- "$f"; done
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 4142 Aug 11 16:03 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug 11 15:34 'name-with-backslash\'
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug 11 15:34 -name-with-dash-prefix
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug 11 15:34 'name-with-double-quote"'
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug 11 15:34 "name-with-single-quote'"
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug 11 15:34 'name with space'
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug 11 15:34 safe-name
```

Comment: "In any case, your basic approach is wrong to begin with. Instead of fiddling about with xargs and ls and whatnot, just use shell globs instead". i should've added that I specifically asked about solution that involves xargs, because the names do not necessarily come from filenames, and I want to pass multiple arguments to a single command, not one argument to one command.

Comment: "And there's no need to use the -- with ls when run via xargs, xargs can deal with that properly itself:" it seems that -- is actually needed, e.g.: `ls -- *dash* | xargs ls` result in error while `ls -- *dash* | xargs ls --` is okay. `xargs` does not automatically add an extra `--` argument and the second `ls` needs it to separate the name from options.

Comment: @GerryLufwansa ah! That's a very different proposition then, yes. You can probably still use the shell loop (personally, I think I never use `xargs` and always write such loops), but we might be abe to give you a better solution for your use case if you clarify what you'll be doing.

Comment: @GerryLufwansa huh. You're absolutely right. That's odd, I guess `xargs` only does that when run with `-0`. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremelly silly to try to [parse the output of a command `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that is [not designed to be parsed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/232326) to feed a command which [is not designed to deal with several characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243736/xargs-and-newlines-in-txt-files-xargs-d-n-is-failing) (for example: `new lines` and `{}`) when the shell does that by itself:

```
set -- *; for f; do echo "<$f>"; done

set    -- *
for    f
do     ls "$f"
done
```

Or, in one command line:

```
$ set -- *; for f; do echo "<$f>"; done
<name-with-backslash\>
<-name-with-dash-prefix>
<name-with-double-quote">
<name-with-single-quote'>
<name with space>
<safe-name>
<with_a
newline>
```

Note that the output deals (and has n example as last filename) with new-lines perfectly fine.

Or, if the number of files makes the shell slow, use find:

```
$ find ./ -type f -exec echo '<{}>' \;
<./safe-name>
<./with_a
newline>
<./name-with-double-quote">
<./-name-with-dash-prefix>
<./name with space>
<./name-with-single-quote'>
<./name-with-backslash\>
```

Just mind that find process all dot-files and all sub-directories diferently than the shell.

Comment: If only `find` can feed multiple filenames to a single command, so we don't need `xargs`, that'd be nice.

Comment: And indeed, not only can find [use multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043896/8017719), but it can [execute multiple commands with the same argument using the `-exec sh` concept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227671/232326) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102203/232326). @GerryLufwansa

Comment: BTW, in the question `ls` is just an example. This is not about whether we should or should not be parsing the output of `ls`. What I asked is how to handle characters like double quote or newline in `xargs`, and the answer provided by others is to use -0 and to feed it null-separated names instead of newline-separated. Your answer is irrelevant in this case because I was asking specifically about `xargs`.

Comment: About `find`, what I commented was about feeding multiple *arguments* to a *single* command, not about using/running *multiple commands*.

Comment: And lastly, using `find -exec` is sometimes inadequate. When we want to limit the number of results, we must feed the output of `find` to `head` or `tail` first, as `find` cannot limit number of results by itself. When we want to sort the results e.g. by mtime, size, etc we need to use other tools because `find` does not do sorting.

Comment: I may have not explain it clearly: [Seaech for "Using ‑exec Efficiently:", specially for "There are standard POSIX (but non-obvious) solutions to both problems."](https://wpollock.com/Unix/FindCmd.htm) @GerryLufwansa

Comment: Ah thanks! So `-exec` *can* collect multiple filenames, simply by replacing the usual backspace with plus sign. I wonder why this is not more widely known.