# Can't rename the directories getting error: Invalid cross-device link

Tags: files, regular-expression, rename

How to replace `%002E` with a dot(`.`) from all the directories and sub-directories name.

I tried the below command but it's not working

```
find . | rename -v "s/%002E/./g"
```

getting this error when I ran on a single file

```
Can't rename ./doc%002Ejson ./doc.json: Invalid cross-device link
Can't rename ./doc%002Ejson/fileData ./doc.json/fileData: No such file or directory
Can't rename ./doc%002Ejson/metadata ./doc.json/metadata: No such file or directory
Can't rename ./fontDef%002Ejson ./fontDef.json: Invalid cross-device link
Can't rename ./fontDef%002Ejson/fileData ./fontDef.json/fileData: No such file or directory
Can't rename ./fontDef%002Ejson/metadata ./fontDef.json/metadata: No such file or directory
```

edit:
tired `find -depth -type d | rename -n "s/%002E/./g"` as well

I only see

```
rename(./doc%002Ejson, ./doc.json)
rename(./fontDef%002Ejson, ./fontDef.json)
rename(./listDef%002Ejson, ./listDef.json)
rename(./styleDef%002Ejson, ./styleDef.json)
```

but when I do ls I still see
`doc%002Ejson` instead of `doc.json`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename multiple files using find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227662/how-to-rename-multiple-files-using-find) (just use `-type d` instead of `-type f` to only look for directories).

Comment: No. I tried with -type d. but getting this error:
'Can't rename ./doc%002Ejson ./doc.json: Invalid cross-device link
Can't rename ./fontDef%002Ejson ./fontDef.json: Invalid cross-device link
Can't rename ./listDef%002Ejson ./listDef.json: Invalid cross-device link
Can't rename ./styleDef%002Ejson ./styleDef.json: Invalid cross-device link'

Comment: Please try this and [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/611173/edit) with the results `find -depth -type d | rename -n "s/%002E/./g"`

Comment: What OS are you running this on? On my CentOS box, `find . | rename -v "s/%002E/./g"` returns: `rename: not enough arguments`. The command `find . | xargs -l rename -v "%002E" "."` seems to give me the results you are expecting.