# Bulk renaming of camelcase files to include spaces

Tags: find, rename, xargs

I'm attempting a batch rename of camelcase-named files to include spaces between adjacent upper and lower case leters. I'm using Mac OS so the utils I'm using are the BSD-variant.

For example:

```
250 - ErosPhiliaAgape.mp3 => 250 - Eros Philia Agape.mp3
```

I'm trying to `find` the relevant files and pipe them to `mv` which runs `sed` in a subshell, using this command:

```
find . -name "*[a-z][A-Z]*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} "$(sed -E 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g')"
```

Individually, these commands work fine: `find` pulls up the correct files and `sed` renames it correctly, but when I combine them with xargs, nothing happens.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: BTW, there's also a Perl-based `rename` which allows you to rename multiple files using Perl regexps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `$(...)` sub-shell in your command is evaluated at the time you run the command, and not evaluated by `xargs` for each file.
You could use `find`'s `-exec` instead to evaluate commands for each file in a `sh`, and also replace the quoting appropriately:

```
find . -name "*[a-z][A-Z]*" -type f -exec sh -c 'echo mv -v "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed -E "s/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g")"' \;
```

If the output of this looks good, drop the `echo` in `echo mv`.
Note that due to `echo | sed`, this won't work with filenames with embedded `\n`. (But that was an already existing limitation in your own attempt, so I hope that's acceptable.)

Comment: Note that since `{}` is replaced by the file name, this will choke if the file name contains shell special characters, in this case `$"\\\``. You should never include `{}` inside a shell snippet, always pass it as a separate arguments. Some implementations of `find` and `xargs` wisely substitute `{}` only when it's the argument; if your version substitutes it when it's a substring of an argument, that's almost never desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sed` command is taking input from the pipe. It's competing with `xargs`, so each of the two commands will get part of the data written by `find` (each byte goes to only one reader), and it's unpredictable which receives what.

You would need to pipe each file name into `sed`, which means you need an intermediate shell to set up the pipe.

```
find . -name "*[a-z][A-Z]*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(echo "$0" | sed -E '\''s/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g'\'')"' {}
```

You don't need `xargs`, it's mostly useless. `find` can call a program directly.

```
find . -name "*[a-z][A-Z]*" -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(echo "$0" | sed -E '\''s/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g'\'')"' {} \;
```

Alternatively, [install](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cpan.1.html) any of the Perl `rename` implementations, for example [`File::Rename`](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/lib/File/Rename.pm) or the one from [`Unicode::Tussle`](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Unicode-Tussle-1.111/lib/Unicode/Tussle.pm).

```
cpan File::Rename
find -depth . -exec rename 's!([a-z])([A-Z])(?!.*/)!$1 $2!g' {} +
```

The `(?!.*/)` bit prevents the replacement from triggering in directory names, in case they contain camelcase. Passing `-depth` to `find` ensures that if a directory is renamed, this happens after `find` has traversed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using GNU Parallel the solution is:

```
find . -name "*[a-z][A-Z]*" -type f | parallel mv -v {} '{= s:([a-z])([A-Z])(?!.*/):$1 $2:g =}'
```