# Why doesn't GNU parallel work with "bash -c"?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, gnu-parallel

```
% echo -e '1\n2' | parallel "bash -c 'echo :\$1' '' {}"
:1
:2
% echo -e '1\n2' | parallel bash -c 'echo :\$1' '' {}


%
```

I'd expect the second line to act the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`parallel` runs the command in a shell already (which shell it is is determined by `parallel` using heuristics (the intention being to invoke the same shell as the one `parallel` was invoked *from*). You can set the `$PARALLEL_SHELL` variable to fix the shell).

It's not a command you're passing to `parallel` like you would for the `env` or `xargs` command, but a shell command line (like you would for the `eval` command).

Like for `eval`, in `parallel arg1 arg2`, `parallel` is concatenating those arguments with spaces in between (so it becomes `arg1 arg2`) and that string is passed to `<the-shell> -c`.

For the arguments that are passed on `parallel`'s stdin, `parallel` quotes them in the format expected by that particular shell (a difficult and error prone task which is why you'll find there have been a lot of bugs fixed around that in `parallel`'s Changelog ([some](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2016-11/msg00000.html) are still  not fixed as of 2017-03-06)) and appends it to that command line.

So for instance, if called from within `bash`,

```
echo "foo'bar" | parallel echo foo
```

Would have parallel call `bash -c` with `echo foo foo\'bar` as the command line. And if called from within `rc` (or with `PARALLEL_SHELL=rc`) `rc -c` with `echo foo foo''''bar`.

In your:

```
parallel bash -c 'echo :\$1' '' {}
```

`parallel` concatenates those arguments which gives:

```
bash -c echo :$1  {}
```

And with the `{}` expanded and quoted in the right format for the shell you're calling `parallel` from, passes that to `<that-shell> -c` which will call `bash -c echo` with `:$1` in `$0` and the current argument in `$1`.

It's not how `parallel` works. Here, you'd probably want:

```
printf '1\n2\n' | PARALLEL_SHELL=bash parallel 'echo :{}'
```

To see what `parallel` does, you can run it under `strace -fe execve` (or the equivalent on your system if not Linux).

Here, you could use GNU `xargs` instead of `parallel` to get a simpler processing closer to what you're expecting:

```
printf '1\n2\n' | xargs -rn1 -P4 bash -c 'echo ":$1"' ''
```

See also the discussion at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html

Note that in `bash -c 'echo foo' '' foo`, you're making `$0` the empty string for that inline-script. I would avoid that as that `$0` is also used in error messages. Compare:

```
$ bash -c 'echo x > "$1"' '' /
: /: Is a directory
```

with.

```
$ bash -c 'echo x > "$1"' bash /
bash: /: Is a directory
```

Also note that leaving variables unquoted has a very special meaning in `bash` and that `echo` can generally not be used for arbitrary data.

Comment: Mon dieu! This is a better answer than the author of GNU Parallel could have written.

Comment: Four years later, I still think this handling GNU parallel's mumbling of the input is inappropriate... It's literally unusable.