# "run any command which will pass untrusted data to commands which interpret arguments as commands"

Tags: shell

From findutils' manual:

> For example constructs such as these two commands
>
> ```
> # risky
> find -exec sh -c "something {}" \;
> find -execdir sh -c "something {}" \;
> ```
>
> are very dangerous. The reason for this is that the ‘{}’ is expanded
>   to a filename which might contain a semicolon or other characters
>   special to the shell. If for example someone creates the file
>   `/tmp/foo; rm -rf $HOME` then the two commands above could delete
>   someone’s home directory.
>
> So for this reason do not run any command which will pass untrusted
>   data (such as the names of fi les) to commands which interpret
>   arguments as commands to be further interpreted (for example ‘sh’).
>
> In the case of the shell, there is a clever workaround for this
>   problem:
>
> ```
> # safer
> find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh {} \;
> find -execdir sh -c 'something "$@"' sh {} \;
> ```
>
> This approach is not guaranteed to avoid every problem, but it is much
>   safer than substituting data of an attacker’s choice into the text of
>   a shell command.

1. Is the cause of the problem in `find -exec sh -c "something {}" \;` that the replacement for `{}` is
   unquoted and therefore not treated as a single string?
2. In the solution `find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh {} \;`,

   - first `{}` is replaced, but since `{}` is unquoted, doesn't `"$@"` also have the same problem as the original command? For example,
     `"$@"` will be expanded to `"/tmp/foo;"`, `"rm"`, `"-rf"`, and
     `"$HOME"`?
   - why is `{}` not escaped or quoted?
3. Could you give other examples (still with `sh -c`, or without it if
   applicable; with or without `find` which may be not necessary) where the same kind of problem and solution apply, and
   which are  minimal examples so that we can focus on the problem and
   solution with little distraction as possible? See [Ways to provide arguments to a command executed by `bash -c`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448453/ways-to-provide-arguments-to-a-command-executed-by-bash-c)

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This isn’t really related to quoting, but rather to argument processing.

Consider the risky example:

```
find -exec sh -c "something {}" \;
```

- This is parsed by the shell, and split into six words: `find`, `-exec`, `sh`, `-c`, `something {}` (no quotes any more), `;`. There’s nothing to expand.  The shell runs `find` with those six words as arguments.
- When `find` finds something to process, say `foo; rm -rf $HOME`, it replaces `{}` with `foo; rm -rf $HOME`, and runs `sh` with the arguments `sh`, `-c`, and `something foo; rm -rf $HOME`.
- `sh` now sees `-c`, and as a result parses `something foo; rm -rf $HOME` ([the first non-option argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash)) and executes the result.

Now consider the safer variant:

```
find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh {} \;
```

- The shell runs `find` with the arguments `find`, `-exec`, `sh`, `-c`, `something "$@"`, `sh`, `{}`, `;`.
- Now when `find` finds `foo; rm -rf $HOME`, it replaces `{}` again, and runs `sh` with the arguments `sh`, `-c`, `something "$@"`, `sh`, `foo; rm -rf $HOME`.
- `sh` sees `-c`, and parses `something "$@"` as the command to run, and `sh` and `foo; rm -rf $HOME` as the positional parameters ([starting from `$0`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash)), expands `"$@"` to `foo; rm -rf $HOME` *as a single value*,   and runs  `something` with the single argument `foo; rm -rf $HOME`.

You can see this by using `printf`. Create a new directory, enter it, and run

```
touch "hello; echo pwned"
```

Running the first variant as follows

```
find -exec sh -c "printf \"Argument: %s\n\" {}" \;
```

produces

```
Argument: .
Argument: ./hello
pwned
```

whereas the second variant, run as

```
find -exec sh -c 'printf "Argument: %s\n" "$@"' sh {} \;
```

produces

```
Argument: .
Argument: ./hello; echo pwned
```

Comment: In the safer variant, why is `{}` not escaped or quoted?

Comment: It generally doesn’t need to be quoted; it would only need to be quoted in a shell where it has some other meaning, and I don’t think that’s the case with any of the main shells in use nowadays.

Comment: From https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Single-File: "Both of these constructions (`;` and `{}`) need to be escaped (with a ‘\’)
or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell." Do you mean that it is incorrect for bash?

Comment: I mean that it is incorrect for shells in general. See [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_16). That particular statement in the `findutils` manual dates back to at least 1996... Of course it does no harm to quote `{}`, either as `'{}'` or `"{}"`, but it isn’t necessary.

Comment: @Tim You're experiencing a common situation where your intuition isn't yet accounting for the fact that there are two very different types of argument-processing going on here: when/how the *shell* parses arguments out of a line of text (which is where quoting matters) is different from raw operating system argument passing (where quotes are just regular characters). In the shell command `find some/path -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' {} \;` there's actually *three* layers of argument processing/passing, two of the shell variety and one of the basic raw operating system variety.

Comment: @Tim To address your last comment specifically, now that I've made the general observation in my last comment: `{}` doesn't need quoting there because here's how it goes through each "layer:" 1) to the shell that invokes the entire command, `{}` is just a literal string containing those two characters; 2) `find` doesn't do any special interpretation, it just takes each found path (a literal string), and passes it directly as a single argument at the operating system level to the command it, in turn, invokes; 3) so the `sh` invoked by `find` sees the path verbatim as one argument.

Comment: Also try with a file called `$(echo hello)`, or `$(sudo reboot)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, hmm, I can't seem to get zsh to misbehave with `{}`, it seems to pass it along just fine even unquoted. Do you happen to have any details on that, i.e. is there some particular option or such that would break it?

Comment: Hmm. Last time I was a zsh user was mid-2000s, so my recollections are prone to be unreliable both from age of the memory, and from changes in the interim; if it can't be reproduced today, I'm going to need to retract that from the set of facts I think I know.

Comment: @Tim please don’t comment in your edits. I’ve updated the answer; it’s particularly important to get the quotes right in the explanations IMO — they are parsed away very early on, and what really matters isn’t the quotes but how the command line is split up into tokens (or individual arguments for subsequent commands).

Answer (score 3):

Part 1:

`find` just uses text replacement.

Yes, if you did it unquoted, like this:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "echo {}" \;
```

and an attacker was able to create a file called `; echo owned`, then it would exec

```
sh -c "echo ; echo owned"
```

which would result in the shell running `echo` then `echo owned`.

But if you added quotes, the attacker could just end your quotes then put the malicious command after it by creating a file called `'; echo owned`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "echo '{}'" \;
```

which would result in the shell running `echo ''`, `echo owned`.

(if you swapped the double quotes for single quotes, the attacker could use the other type of quotes too.)

---

Part 2:

In `find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh {} \;`, the `{}` is not initially interpreted by the shell, it's executed directly with `execve`, so adding shell quotes wouldn't help.

```
find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh "{}" \;
```

has no effect, since the shell strips the double quotes before running `find`.

```
find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh "'{}'" \;
```

adds quotes that the shell doesn't treat specially, so in most cases it just means the command won't do what you want.

Having it expand to `/tmp/foo;`, `rm`, `-rf`, `$HOME` shouldn't be a problem, because those are arguments to `something`, and `something` probably doesn't treat its arguments as commands to execute.

---

Part 3:

I assume similar considerations apply for anything that takes untrusted input and runs it as (part of) a command, for example `xargs` and `parallel`.

Comment: `xargs` is only dangerous if `-I` or `-J` is used. In normal operation it's only appending arguments to the end of the list, just as `-exec ... {} +` does.

Comment: (`parallel`, by contrast, runs a shell by default without explicit request from the user, increasing the vulnerable surface; this is a matter that's been the subject of much discussion; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349483/why-doesnt-gnu-parallel-work-with-bash-c for an explanation, and the included link to https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You mean "_decreasing_ the vulnerable surface". The attack illustrated by OP does indeed _not_ work by default with GNU Parallel.

Comment: The reason for spawning a shell is POLA: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#Always-running-commands-in-a-shell

Comment: Yes, I know you need it for parity across SSH -- **if** you didn't spawn a remote `parallel` "receiver" process on the other end of any socket, able to do a direct shell-less `execv`. Which is exactly what I would have done, if in your shoes implementing the tool. Having a noninteractive program behave differently based on the current value of `SHELL` is hardly least-astonishment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The only situation `$SHELL` comes into play is when the starting shell cannot be determined. I.e. When started using `exec`, When run as the last command in a shell that `exec`s the last command, When run as the first arg using `system`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#Which-shell-to-use In these rare cases it can be overridden with `$PARALLEL_SHELL`. Your suggestion would make it impossible to do pipes and redirections in the command. See elaboration on https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#Always-running-commands-in-a-shell

Comment: Yes -- I hold that pipes and redirections **should** be impossible unless the user explicitly starts a shell, at which point they get only the explicit behavior of the shell they explicitly started. If one can expect only what an `execv` provides, that's simpler and less astonishing, and a rule that doesn't change across locations/runtime environments.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is the cause of the problem in `find -exec sh -c "something {}" \;` that the replacement for `{}` is unquoted and therefore not treated as a single string?

In a sense, but **quoting cannot help here**. The filename that gets replaced in place of `{}` can contain *any* characters, *including quotes*. Whatever form of quoting was used, the filename could contain the same, and "break out" of the quoting.

> 2. ... but since `{}` is unquoted, doesn't `"$@"` also have the same problem as the original command? For example, `"$@"` will be expanded to `"/tmp/foo;", "rm", "-rf", and "$HOME"`?

No. `"$@"` expands to the positional parameters, as separate words, and *doesn't* split them further. Here, `{}` is an argument to `find` in itself, and `find` passes the current filename also as a distinct argument to `sh`. It's directly available as a variable in the shell script, it's not processed as a shell command itself.

> ... why is `{}` not escaped or quoted?

It doesn't need to be, in most shells. If you run `fish`, it needs to be: `fish -c 'echo {}'` prints an empty line. But it doesn't matter if you quote it, the shell will just remove the quotes.

> 3. Could you give other examples...

Any time you expand a filename (or another uncontrolled string) as-is inside a string that's taken as some kind of code<sup>(*)</sup>, there's a possibility of arbitrary command execution.

For example, this expands `$f` directly the Perl code, and will cause problems if a filename contains a double quote. The quote in the filename will end the quote in the Perl code, and the rest of the filename can contain any Perl code:

```
touch '"; print "HELLO";"'
for f in ./*; do
    perl -le "print \"size: \" . -s \"$f\""
done
```

(The filename has to be a bit weird since Perl parses the whole code up front, before running any of it. So we'll have to avoid a parse error.)

While this passes it safely through an argument:

```
for f in ./*; do
    perl -le 'print "size: " . -s $ARGV[0]' "$f"
done
```

(It doesn't make sense to run another shell directly from a shell, but if you do, it's similar to the `find -exec sh ...` case)

<sub>(* some kind of code includes SQL, so obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/327/ plus explanation:
https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables )</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is precisely the reason why GNU Parallel quotes input:

```
touch "hello; echo pwned"
find . -print0 | parallel -0 printf \"Argument: %s\\n\" {}
```

This will not run `echo pwned`.

It will run a shell, so that if you extend your command, you will not suddenly get a surprise:

```
# This _could_ be run without spawining a shell
parallel "grep -E 'a|bc' {}" ::: foo
# This cannot
parallel "grep -E 'a|bc' {} | wc" ::: foo
```

For further details on the spawning-a-shell issue see: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#Always-running-commands-in-a-shell

Comment: ...that said, `find . -print0 | xargs -0 printf "Argument: %s\n"` is just as safe (or rather, moreso, since with `-print0` one handles filenames with newlines correctly); parallel's quoting is a workaround for a problem *that doesn't exist at all* when no shell is present.

Comment: But as soon as you add `| wc` to the command you need to jump through hoops to make it safe. GNU Parallel is safe by default.

Comment: ITYM: it tries to cover for every quirk of the shell language by the complicated process of carefully quoting everything. That's not nearly as safe as properly storing data in variables, not intermixed with code. Now, if it were to automatically convert that `foo {} | wc` into `sh -c 'foo "$1" | wc` sh {}`, that might be different.