# Why does command injection not work in this example?

Tags: bash, security

Why does command injection not work in

```
$ bash -c "ls \$1" bash '.; echo hello'
ls: cannot access '.;': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'echo': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'hello': No such file or directory
```

while

```
$ bash -c "eval ls \$1" bash '.; echo hello'
```

works?

In the first command, does the first `bash` perform parameter expansion on `$1`, word splitting on the result of expanding `$1`, and then execute the commands?

Thanks.

Originated from [Ways to provide arguments to a command executed by `bash -c`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/448453/674)

related to [Why is this code injection not working?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448738/why-is-this-code-injection-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same process as in ["run any command which will pass untrusted data to commands which interpret arguments as commands"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/448443/86440).

Your first command,

```
bash -c "ls \$1" bash '.; echo hello'
```

is processed as follows:

- `bash` runs with the arguments `-c`, `ls $1`, `bash`, `.; echo hello`. bash reads its arguments, notes the `-c` option with the command `ls $1`, and the extra arguments `bash` and `.; echo hello`;
- when bash expands `ls $1`, it expands to `ls` with the arguments `.;`, `echo`, `hello` and runs that.

The semi-colon would have had to be processed before variable expansion to cause bash to run two different commands.

Your second command,

```
bash -c "eval ls \$1" bash '.; echo hello'
```

is processed as follows:

- `bash` runs with the arguments `-c`, `eval ls $1`, `bash`, `.; echo hello`. bash reads its arguments, notes the `-c` option with the command `eval ls $1` etc.
- after expansion it runs `eval` with the arguments `ls`, `.;`, `echo`, `hello`;
- **`eval`** then causes the arguments to be re-parsed, resulting in the execution of `ls .` followed by  `echo hello`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you construct a command of form `bash -c "somecommand \$1" bash $somevariable`, where command injection works?

Comment: Well the reason is that shell macros are expanded in the interpreter but not in the parser already. As a result, everything that would need syntax parsing does not happen.