# Why is this code injection not working?

Tags: shell, find

```
$ touch '"; echo world "'

$ find .  -exec sh -c 'ls -l "$@"' sh {} \;
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 0 Jun  8 23:13 '"; echo world "'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 0 Jun  8 23:13 './"; echo world "'
```

I was wondering why the beginning and ending double quotes in the filename not paired with the beginning and ending double quotes in `"$@"`, so that `echo world` in the filename can be run?

Is it because a quote must be recognized by `sh` during lexical analysis of the shell command, in order to quote? Here the quotes in the filename appear in the shell command only after parameter expansion, which already passed lexical analysis and is too late for the quotes in the filename to be recognized? Similarly to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448643/674?

Differently, adding `eval` does not make the injection work either, because although `eval` will make `"` and `;` in the filename recognizable by the shell, `"` in the filename will also be removed by the shell:

```
$ find .  -exec sh -c 'eval ls -l "$@"' sh {} \;
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 0 Jun  8 23:13 '"; echo world "'
ls: cannot access './; echo world ': No such file or directory
```

Debug to see what `eval` actually executes:

```
$ find .  -exec sh -c 'echo ls -l "$@"' sh {} \;
ls -l .
ls -l ./"; echo world "

$ ls -l ./"; echo world "
ls: cannot access './; echo world ': No such file or directory
```

Thanks.

On a side note, why are there two items for the same file in the output of `find` command?
since . is a hard link to the current directory, why does find not output about the directly itself but the file under it?

Comment: Regarding your side note, it's because `find .` finds `.`

Comment: Thanks. since `.` is a hard link to the current directory, why does `find` not output about the directly itself but the file under it?

Comment: `find` doesn't output the listing - `ls .` does

Answer (score 2):

> why the beginning and ending double quotes in the filename not paired with the beginning and ending double quotes in `"$@"`

Because variable expansion isn't a straight text replacement. The quotes inside a variable are not processed as quotes, they're just ordinary characters at that point.

This is similar to any variable containing quotes.

```
$ foo='"foo  bar"'
```

The quotes in `foo` don't end the quotes in the command line, there's no word splitting:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$foo"
"foo  bar"
```

And here, there *is* word splitting (because the expansion is not quoted), and quotes in `foo` do nothing to prevent it:

```
$ printf "%s\n" $foo
"foo
bar"
```

The latter one is similar to why the naive way to store a command in a variable doesn't work.

---

As for the `eval`, I don't understand why you'd add it, but still since it involves another round of expansions, you can just put a command substitution in there:

```
$ touch '$(uname -m)'
$ find .  -exec sh -c 'eval ls "$@"' sh {} \;
$(uname -m)
ls: cannot access './x86_64': No such file or directory
```

or a semicolon:

```
$ touch ';uname -m'
$ find .  -exec sh -c 'eval ls "$@"' sh {} \;
;uname -m
;uname -m
x86_64
```

(I'm not sure why that runs the `ls` twice, though.)

---

With a file called `"; echo world "`, the quotes expand as part of the `"$@"`, where `eval` sees them, and since it runs the whole shell processing again, you have a quoted semicolon.

There's no single filename what would work to inject a command in all the vulnerable cases, it depends on the way the command is built.