# Are the following commands equivalent?

Tags: bash, find, security

`$somevariable` may contain whitespaces and other special characters to bash, and introduce security risk. 
Are the following   commands equivalent?  If not, can you rank them?

```
bash -c 'somecommand "$1"' bash "$somevariable"
bash -c "somecommand '$somevariable'"
bash -c "somecommand \"$somevariable\""
```

Are the following   commands equivalent? 
 If not, can you rank them?

```
find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh {} \;
find -exec sh -c "something '{}'" \;
find -exec sh -c "something \"{}\"" \;
find -exec sh -c 'something "{}"' \;
```

I can't find nonequivalence between the commands in each group.

Originated from [Ways to provide arguments to a command executed by `bash -c`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448453/ways-to-provide-arguments-to-a-command-executed-by-bash-c).
Here I would like to figure out whether the reason why findutils manual suggests

```
find -exec sh -c 'something "$@"' sh {} \;
```

instead of

```
find -exec sh -c "something {}" \;
```

is because of

- quoting or
- moving `{}` outside of the command to be executed by `sh -c`

Will the other commands I wrote in the second group above also work equivalently well?

Thanks.

---

To attack `find -exec sh -c "something '{}'" \;` the second command in the `find` group:

```
$ touch "'; echo world '"
$ find . -exec sh -c "ls '{}'" \;
''\''; echo world '\'''
''\''; echo world '\'''
world
```

Comment: Didn't Stephen already answer essentially this question in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448449/170373 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The `bash -c` commands are not the same in at least the following examples:

```
$ var='a
$(uname)'
```

---

```
$ bash -c 'echo "$1"' bash "$var"
a
$(uname)
```

---

```
$ bash -c "echo '$var'"
a
$(uname)
```

---

```
$ bash -c "echo \"$var\""
a
Darwin
```

---

## The `find` commands also differ:

```
$ touch 'a
> $(uname)'
```

---

```
$ find . -exec sh -c 'echo "$@"' sh {} \;
.
./a
$(uname)
```

---

```
$ find . -exec sh -c "echo '{}'" \;
.
./a
$(uname)
```

---

```
$ find . -exec sh -c "echo \"{}\"" \;
.
./a
Darwin
```

---

```
$ find . -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"' \;
.
./a
Darwin
```

---

So it seems that the following allow arbitrary code execution:

- `bash -c "echo \"$var\""`
- `find . -exec sh -c "echo \"{}\"" \;`
- `find . -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"' \;`

Comment: Thanks. I made some change. Are all commands in each group equivalent now?

Comment: @Tim: I've updated

Comment: Thanks. Can you  change the commands to make them equivalent?

Comment: @Tim: I think the alternatives you provided are "equivalent" and the best bet is to simply discard the ones that allow code execution.

Comment: Only the first method is safe: test with a variable containing unbalanced quotes: `var=$'a\n\'foo"$(uname)'` -- this question is similar to SQL injection: constructing code dynamically is fraught; use parameterization.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. How about the group of `find` commands?

Comment: You can test yourself with a similarly named file. I would anticipate similar results.