# find dir with wildcard and run git status not working

Tags: find, git

When I run

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'iptp*' -execdir bash -c "ls {}" \;
```

I get a listing of all dirs named iptp*

When I run

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'iptp*' -execdir bash -c "git status {}" \;
```

I get

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I seems like `git status` is run in the parent dir where find was started.

What do I make wrong?

Comment: Side note: [never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-execdir`, the command is run in the directory containing the match, *i.e.* the parent directory of the directory whose name starts with “iptp”.

You could instead look for `.git` with a *path* matching `iptp*`:

```
find -maxdepth 2 -type -d -name .git -path "*/iptp*/*" -execdir git status \;
```