# find: current filename evaluates to empty in nested command

Tags: find, exec

I am trying to rename a bunch of images in a directory according to their dimensions. To that end, I am building up my command step by step, using of Imagemagik's `identify` command. I currently am using `echo` and plan to switch that to `mv` once `echo` outputs correctly.

```
find * -type f -exec echo "$(identify -format '%w-%h' {})" \;
```

This outputs a bunch of empty lines. However, when I just run it without the echo directly,

```
find * -type f -exec identify -format '%w-%h' {} \;
```

It outputs the dimensions as expected. Why isnt the inner command executing properly?

Comment: Why would you want to do a command substitution and then just `echo`?

Comment: Once I get it to `echo`, Im going to swap that out with a `mv` in order to rename the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$(identify -format %w-%h "$1")"' sh {} \;
```

### Explanation

The problem is with the way bash expands variables

```
find * -type f -exec echo "$(identify -format '%w-%h' {})" \;
```

First bash expands what is in side `$(...)`:

```
find * -type f -exec echo 'identify: unable to open image `{}': No such file or directory...' \;
```

At which point find will use the same exec statement for all commands with a rather useless argument. What you want to do is suppress the bash expansion for inside the finds exec. You can stop bash expanding things by placing them inside single quotes

```
find * -type f -exec echo '$(identify -format %w-%h {})' \;
```

But here we lose expansion completely, we can inject it back by running the expression with `sh -c`

```
find * -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$(identify -format %w-%h {})"' \;
```

Having `{}` within the shell script can also lead to some unexpected errors when dealing with whitespace or quotes or any character special to the shell in file names. To get around this you should move the `{}` as an argument to sh with:

```
find * -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$(identify -format %w-%h "$1")"' sh {} \;
```

*[See this question/answer for a more detailed explanation of this.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely/156010#156010)*

Finally you can replace the `*` with `.` to let `find` find the files in the current directory by itself (and include hidden ones and not fail for filenames starting with `-`).

Additionally, you can add the `-x` flag to `sh` to get it to print out what was it executed to help with debugging the command - this can be very noisy for a lot of files.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/116858

Comment: The `identify: unable to open image...` error will be output by `identify` on its stderr, so won't be captured by `$(...)`. as there won't be anything on stdout, `$(...)` will expand to an empty string, so it's like running `find ... -exec echo '' \;`

Answer (score 2):

That's because `echo` doesn't know what is `{}` inside itself to expand it, only `exec` understand `{}`, in this case you should use in `sh -c` mode.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$(identify -format '%w-%h' "$1")"' sh '{}' \;
```