# How can I move multiple archives with different names using mv in a loop?

Tags: shell-script, files, find, mv, for

I have 2500 archives name LposK.dat with L ranging from 1 to 10 and K ranging from 0.00 to 49.80. I need to move those that have the same K to a folder. I manage to do this using:

```
find . -name '*posK.dat' -exec mv {} ~/destination/K \;
```

But I have to manually change the value of K and repeat it multiple times. I was wondering if there's any way of using the index of a loop (eg: for loop) inside the find and mv commands so that I can write a script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `K` from `LposK.dat`, if that string is in `$name`, we may do

```bash
k=${name%.dat}  # remove ".dat" suffix
k=${k##*pos}    # remove everything up to end of (the last) "pos"
```

This would work even if `$name` was a pathname like `some/path/LposK.dat` (and even if `some/path` contained the string `pos`), which is useful when we later plug it into `find`.

To move one file:

```bash
k=${name%.dat}
k=${k##*pos}

dest="$HOME/destination/$k"
mkdir -p "$dest" && mv "$name" "$dest"  # only move if mkdir did not fail
```

With `find`:

```bash
find . -type f -name '*pos*.dat' -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        k=${name%.dat}
        k=${k##*pos}

        dest="$HOME/destination/$k"
        mkdir -p "$dest" && mv "$name" "$dest"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would give the internal `sh -c` script a number of pathnames as arguments, and the script would iterate over these, moving each one into the correct subdirectory of `$HOME/destination`.

Related:

- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

If your files are in a single subdirectory (the current directory), then you can do this even easier without `find`:

```bash
for name in ./*pos*.dat; do
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue  # skip non-regular files

    k=${name%.dat}
    k=${k##*pos}

    dest="$HOME/destination/$k"
    mkdir -p "$dest" && mv "$name" "$dest"
done
```