# What does "`_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string is used for the shell's error messages" mean?

Tags: bash, find

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/674

> Note that the second `sh` above goes into the inline script's `$0`.
>   You should use something relevant there (like `sh` or `find-sh`), not
>   things like `_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string as that is used for the
>   shell's error messages:
>
> ```
> $ find . -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'echo 0 > "$1"' inline-sh {} \;
> inline-sh: ./accept_ra: Permission denied
> ```

What does "`_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string  is used for the shell's error messages" mean?

Why does using `inline-sh` not work in the example, given that `inline-sh` is not `_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subject of “is used for the shell’s error messages” is “`$0`”, not “`_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string”. The value given to `$0` is used for error messages; so you shouldn’t specify a meaningless value for `$0`, otherwise you’ll end up with weird error messages. It might make more sense as

> Note that the second `sh` above goes into the inline script's `$0`. You should use something relevant there (like `sh` or `find-sh`), not things like `_`, `-`, `--` or the empty string, as the value in `$0` is used for the shell's error messages:

`inline-sh` *does* work in the example: it’s used in the error message, which is the whole point of the example.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ find . -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'echo 0 > "$1"' inline-sh {} \;
inline-sh: ./accept_ra: Permission denied
```

The error  message tells you it's an `inline-sh` that fails to open a `./accept_ra` file.

```
$ find . -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'echo 0 > "$1"' _ {} \;
_: ./accept_ra: Permission denied
$ find . -name accept_ra -exec sh -c 'echo 0 > "$1"' '' {} \;
: ./accept_ra: Permission denied
```

Makes it less obvious and more confusing to the user what is actually failing to open that `./accept_ra`.

Hence the  recommendation to use a meaningful value for that first argument after `sh -c 'code'`. Repeating the command name is generally just fine. As in

```
sh -c 'code using "$@"' sh  actual arguments to the inline script
```