# why does the following `find` command doesn't `ls -l` each file in the current directory?

Tags: find

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 0 Jun  8 16:37 'file; echo hello'
$ find . -exec echo {} \;
.
./file; echo hello
```

I was wondering why the following command doesn't `ls -l` each file in the current directory? Why does it report some file named `1`? Thanks.

```
$ find . -exec sh -c "ls -l $@" sh {} \;
ls: cannot access '1': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '1': No such file or directory

$ find . -exec sh -c "echo ls -l $@" sh {} \;
ls -l 1
ls -l 1
```

Comment: What is `sh` on your system?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, `$@` is expanded by your current shell, before it runs `find`, because it’s in a double-quoted string. I’m guessing you have `$1` set to `1` (run `printf "%s\n" "$@"` to see the current values of the positional parameters).

To run your experiments as I think you intend, you should use single quotes around the command and double quotes around `$@` (to avoid extra splitting); for example:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'ls -l "$@"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks. `find . -exec sh -c 'ls -l "$@"' sh {} \;` seems better, in that it can prevent word splitting which `find . -exec sh -c "ls -l \$@" sh {} \;` and  `find . -exec sh -c "ls -l '$@'" sh {} \;` can't?

Comment: You’re right, I’ve amended my answer.