# get base64 value from openssl md5 command in script

Tags: hashsum

I am trying to get the base64 md5 value of the latest file in an oracle backup directory:

```
 for file in "$(find /oracle/PD1/sapbackup/b*/ -newermt $date -type f)"; do openssl md5 -binary $file | base64 && echo $file >>/md5check/$date/PD1/md5local.txt; done
```

When I run this command I get the full md5 checksum: `Y1l1t+SGpQ7Jh0GZm9R5oTrEvfcGM7NaCuYediMH2MY=`

But I want to get the base64 value:

```
# openssl md5 -binary /oracle/PD1/sapbackup/beyrnmmq/cntrlPD1.dbf | base64
Y1l1t+SGpQ7Jh0GZm9R5oQ==
```

How can I do this using a for loop and output the file path + md5 value to a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [don't loop over the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697).  Instead, use `find` to execute your command.  This ensures that filenames do not get mangled.  For the same reason, you need to [quote your variable expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766).

```
mkdir -p "/md5check/$date/PD1"

find /oracle/PD1/sapbackup/b*/ -type f -newermt "$date" -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "file = %s\n" "$pathname"
        openssl md5 -binary "$pathname" | base64
    done' sh {} + >"/md5check/$date/PD1/md5local.txt"
```

This would find any regular file in or below any of the `/oracle/PD1/sapbackup/b*/` directories that have a modification timestamp newer than `$date`.  For these files, a short script is executed.  The script prints the pathname of the file along with the base64 encoded MD5 checksum.  The output of `find` goes to the indicated file at the end.

The redirection to the output file could obviously be done with `>>` inside the script, but this would mean having to open the output file for writing more than once (also, `$date` is not available in there).

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are asking.

I removed the *-binary* option because I supposed you wanted the md5 hash.

```
for file in "$(find /oracle/PD1/sapbackup/b*/ -newermt $date -type f)"
do 
     MD5=$(openssl md5 $file | awk '{ print $2 }')
     BASE64=$(echo $MD5 | base64)
     echo "$file : md5 => [ ${MD5} ] / base64 => [ ${BASE64} ]" >> /md5check/$date/PD1/md5local.txt
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much Val. When I run your script I get the following:
<br>
`# cat /md5check/20180613/PD1/md5local.txt           
/oracle/PD1/sapbackup/beyrnmmq/cntrlPD1.dbf
/oracle/PD1/sapbackup/beyrnmmq/BEYRNMMQ.INCR : md5 => [ 635975b7e486a50ec98741999bd479a13ac4bdf70633b35a0ae61e762307d8c6 ] / base64 => [ NjM1OTc1YjdlNDg2YTUwZWM5ODc0MTk5OWJkNDc5YTEgM2FjNGJkZjcwNjMzYjM1YTBhZTYxZTc2MjMwN2Q4YzYK ]`
I can see what you are getting at though. It doesn't spit out the base64 value, but you are on the right track I believe. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try to replace 
BASE64=$(echo $MD5 | base64) with 
BASE64=$(openssl md5 -binary $file | base64)

Comment: Thanks @Val F
I got it going now - by cutting the code down like this:
`for file in $(find /oracle/PD1/sapbackup/b*/ -newermt $date -type f);
do 
     MD5=$(openssl md5 -binary $file)
     echo $MD5 | base64 >> /md5check/$date/PD1/md5local.txt
done`
I've removed the quotation marks around the 'for' statement and now it spits out the base64 value to a file. I'll work with this because I need to now grab those md5 values into an S3api command and compare files locally with those stored in an S3 bucket.
Much appreciated for your help!
Cheers

Comment: Don't loop over the output of `find`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697