# Using find to rename a directory into the trash directory

Tags: shell-script, find, filenames, mv

The following is checking for any folder in the path that is more than 1 day old and matches the name criteria. If found, the folder is then moved to the 'trash' folder.

```
find /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/websites/testwebsite.co.uk -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +1 -name '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -exec mv {} /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/trash \;
```

I need to modify the foldername, to include '_renamed' at the end.

I thought that I could use the curly braces from mv, but now realise this takes the full folder path as well.

```
find /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/websites/testwebsite.co.uk -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +1 -name '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -exec mv {} /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/trash/{}_renamed \;
```

Is there any way that I can modify the folder path without copying the path as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `find` works with pathnames, not filenames.

There are two immediate solutions:

1. You could extract the filename portion of the pathname, and use that in the destination pathname used by `mv`.

   ```
   find /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/websites/testwebsite.co.uk \
       -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +1 \
       -name '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
       -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "/Users/myname/Desktop/backups/trash/${1##*/}_renamed"' sh {} ';'
   ```

   Here, `${1##*/}` is the same as `$( basename "$1" )`, and `$1` is the pathname given to the `sh -c` script by `find`.
2. You could use `-execdir` in place of `-exec` if your `find` implementation supports it.  With `-execdir`, the given command is executed in the parent folder of the found item, and `{}` will be either the basename of the item (with BSD `find`) or the basename prefixed by `./` (with GNU `find`).

   ```
   find /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/websites/testwebsite.co.uk \
       -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +1 \
       -name '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
       -execdir mv {} /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/trash/{}_renamed ';'
   ```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)
- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely)

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! I had not heard of 'execdir'. This was perfect.