# Listing number of files in each folder where folder name matches a pattern

Tags: bash, find, ls, xargs, wc

I would like to recursively search a directory tree and list the number of files available in each folder that have a name corresponding to a given string. In effect, I would like to return results of:

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

for each folder I've identified via `find`.

## Code

The code below correctly lists number of files in each folder that name contains *Magic Data* string.

```
find /path/to/cool/stuff                        \         
        -maxdepth 4                             \         
        -type d                                 \         
        -name '*Magic Data*'                    \         
        -print0 | xargs                         \         
                --verbose                       \         
                -0 -I {} ls -l {}
```

I would like to expand it and pipe results of `ls` to `wc -l`.

### Attempt

```
find /path/to/cool/stuff                        \         
        -maxdepth 4                             \         
        -type d                                 \         
        -name '*Magic Data*'                    \         
        -print0 | xargs                         \         
                --verbose                       \         
                -0 -I {} ls -l {}  | wc -l
```

This fails and prints:

```
ls -l /path/to/cool/stuff/some/folders/Magic Data
ls -l /path/to/cool/stuff/some/folders2/Magic Data
```

## Desired output

```
/path/to/cool/stuff/some/folders/Magic Data  29
/path/to/cool/stuff/some/folders2/Magic Data 30
```

Desired output would contain:

- Full path to the searched folder
- Output of `wc -l`, which in this case reflects count of non-hidden files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways of solving this:

1. Modify the `find` command so that it only enters the directories that you are interested in and then prints a single character (e.g. `x`) for each found file within. Then count the number of that character produced with `wc -l`.  It's safer to output a character than the pathname as pathnames in Unix could potentially contain newlines.  This solution is a bit tricky as it involves using `-prune` to ignore directories we're not interested in, or alternatively `! -path`.
2. Find the directories just like you've done so far, but then use an in-line script to do the counting of files within.  This is simpler, and what I'm showing below.

```
find /path/to/cool/stuff -maxdepth 4 -type d -name "*Magic Data*' \
    -exec bash -O dotglob -c '
        dir=$1
        set -- "$dir"/*
        printf "%s %d\n" "$dir" "$#"' bash {} ';'
```

Here, we find the directories like you do, then, for each directory, we run this short `bash` script:

```bash
dir=$1
set -- "$dir"/*
printf "%s %d\n" "$dir" "$#"
```

This takes the pathname of the directory from the command line (given by `find`), and expands the `*` glob pattern within it.  By setting the `dotglob` shell option on the command line for the script, we are guaranteed to also count hidden files and directories (remove `-O dotglob` to not count hidden names).

We do the expansion of all names as an argument to `set`, which will set the positional parameters to the expanded entries. The number of positional parameters is available as `$#`, which is therefore also the count of files in that particular directory.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your attempted solution, this is how one could accomplish this task:

```
find /path/to/cool/stuff                        \         
        -maxdepth 4                             \         
        -type d                                 \          
        -name '*Magic Data*'                    \
        -exec sh -c '
           for d do
              printf "%s: " "$PWD/$d"
              find "$d/." -maxdepth 1 ! -name . -printf "\\n" | wc -l
           done
       ' find_sh {} +
```

**Explanation:**

- Up until the point of `find`-*ing* the target directories, your recipe is followed.
- Once we locate the target directories, meaning those which have the string "Magic Data" somewhere in their basenames, we gather them in a bunch `{} +`, and hand them over to the shell `sh` via it's arguments list: `sh -c '...' find_sh {} +`
- The initial argument of `sh` which is the zeroth argument `$0` and as such it can be given any name, and here in this case we name it `find_sh`. This is the name that'll show up in the process list.
- The target directories bunch goes inside the `{} +` and form the `$1 $2 $3 ...` arguments to the shell we are spawning.
- Inside that shell we just launched, we emit a newline for every file found in the target directories except itself, i.e., `! -name .` OTW, the target directory name also gets counted into the wc -l output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command to achieve what you want

Here I am using `exec` to execute `sh` shell which is then executing command given to it by using `-c` option . In your case the command is `ls -1 | wc -l`

```
find /path/to/cool/stuff    -maxdepth 4  -type d  -name '*Magic Data*' -print0 -exec sh -c "ls -1 {} | wc -l" \;
```

Comment: Regarding using `{}` in an embedded shell script: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008