# Xargs to extract filename

Tags: awk, find, xargs, echo

I would like to find all the `.html` files in a folder and append `[file](./file.html)` to another file called `index.md`. I tried the following command:

```
ls | awk "/\.html$/" | xargs -0 -I @@ -L 1 sh -c 'echo "[${@@%.*}](./@@)" >> index.md'
```

But it can't substitute `@@` inside the command? What am I doing wrong?

Note: Filename can contain valid characters like space

---

Clarification:

`index.md` would have each line with `[file](./file.html)` where file is the actual file name in the folder

Comment: `xargs -0` implies null-terminated strings on the `xargs` stdin, but `awk` does not print them. `${}` needs a variable name. Both points are addressed in @RoVo's answer

Comment: Would you please clarify how the content of "index.md" will look like?

Comment: @Goro I had appended the clarification at the end of question, but unfortunately, it has been edited out!

Comment: @Nikhil. Would you please include it again. Thanks!

Comment: @Goro Isn't it appropriate to justify accepted answer?

Comment: @Nikhil. Please review this https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Goro It does not say that the OP can't justify why he has chosen a particular answer. These are guidelines. In the case where multiple answers are worth accepting, I think the explanation by OP adds value to the community.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do:

```
for f in *.html; do printf '%s\n' "[${f%.*}](./$f)"; done > index.md
```

Use `set -o nullglob` (`zsh`, `yash`) or `shopt -s nullglob` (`bash`) for `*.html` to expand to nothing instead of `*.html` (or report an error in `zsh`) when there's no `html` file. With `zsh`, you can also use `*.html(N)` or in `ksh93` `~(N)*.html`.

Or with one `printf` call with `zsh`:

```
files=(*.html)
rootnames=(${files:r})
printf '[%s](./%s)\n' ${basenames:^files} > index.md
```

Note that, depending on which markdown syntax you're using, you may have to HTML-encode the *title* part and URI-encode the URI part if the file names contain some problematic characters. Not doing so could even end up introducing a form of XSS vulnerability depending on context. With ksh93, you can do it with:

```
for f in *.html; do
  title=${ printf %H "${file%.*}"; }
  title=${title//$'\n'/"<br/>"}
  uri=${ printf '%#H' "$file"; }
  uri=${uri//$'\n'/%0A}      
  printf '%s\n' "[$title]($uri)"
done > index.md
```

Where `%H`¹ does the HTML encoding and `%#H` the URI encoding, but we still need to address newline characters separately.

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -MURI::Encode=uri_encode -MHTML::Entities -CLSA -le '
  for (<*.html>) {
     $uri = uri_encode("./$_");
     s/\.html\z//;
     $_ = encode_entities $_;
     s:\n:<br/>:g;
     print "[$_]($uri)"
  }'
```

Using `<br/>` for newline characters. You may want to use ␤ instead or more generally decide on some form of alternative representation for non-printable characters.

There are a few things wrong in your code:

- [parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- use a `$` meant to be literal inside double quotes
- Using `awk` for something that `grep` can do (not wrong per se, but overkill)
- use `xargs -0` when the input is not NUL-delimited
- `-I` conflicts with `-L 1`. `-L 1` is to run one command per line of input but with each word in the line passed as separate  arguments, while `-I @@` runs one command for each line of input with the full line (minus the trailing blanks, and quoting still processed) used to replace `@@`.
- using `{}` inside the *code* argument of `sh` ([command injection vulnerability](/a/156010))
- In `sh`, the `var` in `${var%.*}` is a *variable name*, it won't work with arbitrary text.
- use `echo` for arbitrary data.

If you wanted to use `xargs -0`, you'd need something like:

```
printf '%s\0' * | grep -z '\.html$' | xargs -r0 sh -c '
  for file do
    printf "%s\n" "[${file%.*}](./$file)"
  done' sh > file.md
```

- Replacing `ls` with `printf '%s\0' *` to get a NUL-delimited output
- `awk` with `grep -z` (GNU extension) to process that NUL-delimited output
- `xargs -r0` (GNU extensions) without any `-n`/`-L`/`-I`, because while we're at spawning a `sh`, we might as well have it process as many files as possible
- have `xargs` pass the words as *extra* arguments to `sh` (which become the *positional parameters* inside the inline code), not inside the code argument.
- which means we can more easily store them in variables (here with `for file do` which loops over the positional parameters by default) so we can use the `${param%pattern}` parameter expansion operator.
- use `printf` instead of `echo`.

It goes without saying that it makes little sense to use that instead of doing that `for` loop directly over the `*.html` files like in the top example.

---

<sup>¹ It doesn't seem to work properly for multibyte characters in my version of ksh93 though (ksh93u+ on a GNU system)</sup>

Comment: That overwrites `index.md` though, which OP's code did not.

Comment: I *think* this is still what OP wants. OP uses `>>` because he uses it inside the loop, while this answer after the loop and a second run of the same script doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the answer. But `for f in *.html; do printf '%s\n' "[${f%.*}](./$f)"; done >> index.md` appends  `[*](./*.html)` when no html file exists.

Comment: @Nikhil, see edit.

Answer (score 9):

[Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).
You don't need `xargs` for this, you can use `find -exec`.

try this,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.html" -exec \
    sh -c 'f=$(basename "$1"); echo "[${f%.*}]($1)" >> index.md' sh {} \;
```

If you *want* to use `xargs`, use this very similar version:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'f=$(basename "$1"); echo "[${f%.*}]($1)" >> index.md' sh {} \;
```

Another way without running `xargs` or `-exec`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.html" -printf '[%f](./%f)\n' \
    | sed 's/\.html\]/]/' \
    > index.md
```

Comment: Is that an extra `sh` argument in the first command, or is that intentional?

Comment: This is taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/236063). See comments there and `man sh` -> `-c` for a documentation why this is needed.

Comment: Ah, thanks - I had missed that **If there are arguments  after  the  *command_string*,  the  first  argument  is
                 assigned to `$0` and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.**

Comment: Add '-type f' to avoid strangeness with directories matching "*.html"

Comment: The second command (the one that uses `xargs`) is the one that has safeguards against spaces and carriage returns in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need `xargs`?

```
ls *.html | perl -pe 's/.html\n//;$_="[$_](./$_.html)\n"'
```

(If you have more than 100000 files):

```
printf "%s\n" *.html | perl -pe 's/.html\n//;$_="[$_](./$_.html)\n"'
```

or (slower, but shorter):

```
for f in *.html; do echo "[${f%.*}](./$f)"; done
```

Comment: Note that with `ls *.html`, if any of those `html` files are of type _directory_, `ls` will list their content. More generally, when you use `ls` with a shell wildcard, you want to use `ls -d -- *.html` (which also addresses the issues with file names starting with `-`).

Comment: The first two approaches assume file names don't contain newline characters (anyway, I suppose those would have to be encoded somehow in the markdown syntax). The third one assumes file names don't contain backslash characters. More generally, [`echo` can't be used for arbitrary data](/q/65803).