# How can I add "find exec" command as a function to bashrc?

Tags: bash, find, function

```
find . -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${0/.mov}.mp4"' {} \;
```

Above command works perfectly when I run it manually but I could not put it within a function in the `.bashrc` file. Receiving `unexpected end of line` error.

```
function fff { find . -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${0/.mov}.mp4"' {} \; }
```

Comment: What does the function itself look like?

Comment: Without seeing the actual function definition, this is just a wild guess, but: are you missing a semicolon or line break before the `}` that closes the function definition?

Comment: The in-line `bash` script has a code injection vulnerability. Never embed `{}` in shell code like that. Use `bash -c '...' bash {} \;` instead and then `$1` in the in-line script.

Comment: `function fff { find . -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${0/.mov}.mp4"' {} \; }`

Comment: @Kusalananda, just to be clear (and I know you know this), one should use `"$1"` in the inline script, or the same vulnerability arrives by a different route.  Here's a [good answer by Stéphane Chazelas](/a/156010/112566) explaining that.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I was sloppy. Using `$1` means using it quoted, if the context is such that it needs to be quoted. It's not quite the same vulnerabilities though, as you can't _rewrite a script_ in the same way by just leaving the quotes off an expansion.  With `{}` you actually insert code, so a filename with an odd number of quotes could cause a syntax error, or worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function definition you gave in a comment:

```
function fff { find . -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${0/.mov}.mp4"' {} \; }
```

is missing a semicolon or line break before the `}` that's supposed to end the function definition. The escaped semicolon doesn't count; that's just an argument to `find` that ends the `-exec` primary. This should work:

```
function fff { find . -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${0/.mov}.mp4"' {} \; ; }
#                                                                                                             semicolon here: ^^^
```

...but there are still a couple of problems. First, as @Kusalananda said in a comment, injecting filenames directly into the shell command with `{}` isn't safe; you should pass it as an argument and use that (as `"$1"` etc). You're already doing that, but as `$0` -- that's really supposed to be the command/function/etc name, not a regular argument, so it's better to pass something else (like `find-bash`) as `$0`, and have the actual argument be `$1`.

Second (again pointed out by @Kusalananda), using `${1/.mov}` to remove the old ".mov" suffix might malfunction if the filename has ".mov" somewhere else in the name; `${1%.mov}` will remove it specifically from the end.

Third (and much less importantly), `function` is a nonstandard bashism that many people prefer to avoid; the standard syntax is `funcname() definition`. I'd also prefer to use line breaks rather than semicolons to separate commands. With all these fixes in place, here's what I have:

```
fff() {
    find . -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'echo ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${1%.mov}.mp4"' find-bash {} \;
}
```

Comment: It would also be better to use `"${1%.mov}"` to be sure that it's the filename suffix we're removing and not just some `.mov` anywhere in the file path.  Also use `bash` or `find-bash` or something similar as `$0` rather than `-`.  This string would be used in any error messages generated by the embedded script. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008

Comment: @Kusalananda Good points; stand by for an edit...