# How to find files by file type?

Tags: files, find, file-command, file-types

I know I can find files using `find`: `find . -type f -name 'sunrise'`. Example result:

```
./sunrise
./events/sunrise
./astronomy/sunrise
./schedule/sunrise
```

I also know that I can determine the file type of a file: `file sunrise`. Example result:

```
sunrise: PEM RSA private key
```

But how can I find files by file type?

For example, `my-find . -type f -name 'sunrise' -filetype=bash-script`:

```
./astronomy/sunrise
./schedule/sunrise
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

["File types" on a Unix system](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_164) are things like regular files, directories, named pipes, character special files, symbolic links etc. These are the type of files that `find` can filter on with its `-type` option.

The `find` utility can not by itself distinguish between a "shell script", "JPEG image file" or any other *type of regular file*.  These types of data may however be distinguished by the `file` utility, which looks at particular signatures within the files themselves to determine type of the file contents.

A common way to label the different types of data files is by their [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type), and `file` is able to determine the MIME type of a file.

---

Using `file` with `find` to detect the MIME type of regular files, and use that to only find shell scripts:

```bash
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    case $( file -bi "$1" ) in (*/x-shellscript*) exit 0; esac
    exit 1' sh {} \; -print
```

or, using `bash`,

```bash
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    [[ "$( file -bi "$1" )" == */x-shellscript* ]]' bash {} \; -print
```

Add `-name sunrise` before the `-exec` if you wish to only detect scripts with that name.

The `find` command above will find all regular files in or below the current directory, and for each such file call a short in-line shell script.  This script runs `file -bi` on the found file and exits with a zero exit status if the output of that command contains the string `/x-shellscript`.  If the output does not contain that string, it exits with a non-zero exit status which causes `find` to continue immediately with the next file.  If the file was found to be a shell script, the `find` command will proceed to output the file's pathname (the `-print` at the end, which could also be replaced by some other action).

The `file -bi` command will output the MIME type of the file.  For a shell script on Linux (and most other systems), this would be something like

```
text/x-shellscript; charset=us-ascii
```

while on systems with a slightly older variant of the `file` utility, it may be

```
application/x-shellscript
```

The common bit is the `/x-shellscript` substring.

Note that on macOS, you would have to use `file -bI` instead of `file -bi` because of *reasons* (the `-i` option does something quite different).  The output on macOS is otherwise similar to that of a Linux system.

---

Would you want to perform some custom action on each found shell script, you could do that with another `-exec` in place of the `-print` in the `find` commands above, but it would also be possible to do

```bash
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        case $( file -bi "$pathname" ) in
            */x-shellscript*) ;;
            *) continue
        esac

        # some code here that acts on "$pathname"

    done' sh {} +
```

or, with `bash`,

```bash
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        [[ "$( file -bi "$pathname" )" != */x-shellscript* ]] && continue

        # some code here that acts on "$pathname"

    done' bash {} +
```

---

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 3):

You could exec `file` on every found file and then grep for the result you're interested in.

```
# When looking for ASCII Text
find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep "ASCII"
# or for MS Word Documents
find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep "Microsoft Word"
```

I suggest to make the search pattern as close as possible to your expectation to keep the number of the false positive matches low.

Beware that files with newlines in their filenames may cause issues with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if this is what one looks for, but:Like this?

`find DIRECTORY -name "*.EXT" -type f -exec COMMAND {} \;`

Where you replace:

> DIRECTORY with the directory to search for files in (and, opt. Operate
> on)

> -name "*.EXT" is the Extension, *wildcard means everything, so  everything ending at "EXT" (, *every file that ends with extension

> EXT*)

> -type f is , file. (type file, not Directory e.g)

> -exec COMMAND is executing COMMAND on every found file with the extension EXT at the end to them.

E.g, calculate the sha512 sum on all files with the .odt extension, inside directory Docs/:

```
find Docs/ -name "*.odt" -type f -exec sha512sum {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter form that doesn't involve that much shell magic:

`find . -exec sh -c "file '{}' | grep -q 'pattern'" \; -print`

Comment: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks a lot for the point out! my gosh; there are many things to miss in best practices n good guidelines!

once again,  thanks!

Comment: Yep, that is a good point. This command would fail if the name contains `'`. In my case, I knew that the file names are "reasonable", so I could ignore that caveat, but in general this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`'s `File::LibMagic` module:

```
perl -MFile::LibMagic=:easy -MFile::Find -le '
  find sub {
    print $File::Find::name if
      $_ eq "sunrise" and
      -f and
      MagicFile$_ eq "PEM RSA private key"
  }, @ARGV' -- .
```

`File::LibMagic` uses the same algorithms and bank of heuristics to guess a file's type as `file`, but here since everything is done in one `perl` invocation, it's much more efficient than having to run one `file` invocation for each file.