# Testing whether variable has valid video file extension

Tags: bash, filenames

How can I test whether a variable has a valid video file extension (`.mp4`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a shell pattern comparison in e.g. `bash`:

```bash
if [[ $variable == *.mp4 ]]; then
    printf 'String "%s" ends in ".mp4"\n' "$variable"
else
    printf 'String "%s" has some other suffix\n' "$variable"
fi
```

or, using a standard `case` statement, which may be prettier if you want to compare many suffix strings,

```
case $variable in
    *.mp4)
        printf 'String "%s" ends in ".mp4"\n' "$variable"
        ;;
    *.mov)
        printf 'String "%s" ends in ".mov"\n' "$variable"
        ;;
    *.blarg|*.foo)
        printf 'String "%s" ends in ".blarg" or ".foo"\n' "$variable"
        ;;

    *)
        printf 'String "%s" has some other suffix\n' "$variable"
esac
```

If your variable contains a pathname and you want to test whether the file at that pathname is a file in a video format, it would (possibly) be better to ask the `file` command to classify the file's contents.  This is because files on Unix systems are arbitrary, and a directory may be called `my video.mp4` even though it's clearly not a video file.

You can get the MIME-type of a file using `file -i` (here, I'm also using `file` with its `-b` option for "brief" output, without the filename):

```bash
$ file -b -i 'video/the_amazing_spiderman_trailer.mp4'
video/mp4; charset=binary
```

This could be used in a script:

```
if file -b -i "$variable" | grep -q -F 'video/mp4;'
then
    printf '"%s" is most likely an MP4 video\n' "$variable"
fi
```

In the code above, it does not matter what suffix string `$variable` contains.

Note that I'm testing this on a FreeBSD system and that the output of `file` is not standard.  You need to test on your local machine.   Also note that the `file` command on macOS uses `-I` in place of `-i`.

A somewhat related question with more info about `file` in my answer to it:

- [How to find files by file type?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483871/how-to-find-files-by-file-type)

Comment: Also (unless in Linux) to get only the mime-type: `file --mime-type -b file.mp4`