# finding files with missing or old signatures

Tags: linux, find

To update signatures in `/boot` I'd like to use find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0.

I know I can just loop and check if the signature matches with gpg, but I'd like to know how to use find with `-newer` in the same directory and use the currently matched pattern somehow to test if file.img is not newer than file.img.sig. Can this be easily done?

i.e. something like:

```
sigs=(`find /boot -type f -iname '*.sig'`)
for sig in ${sigs[@]}; do
  file=${sig%*.sig}
  find /boot -type f -name "$file" -newer /boot -type f -name "$sig"
done
```

Comment: what about `-newer "$sig"` ? But your first line as well as your `for` loop declaration will not work ... Also looping over find result with a for-loop is not what you should do...

Comment: Indeed I was wondering if it were possible without shell expansion or for loop, using only find. (I did not test the above, it was meant to illustrate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops with `find` results can often be replaced by `find -exec`:

Try something like this,

```
find /boot -type f -iname '*.sig' \
    -exec sh -c 'find /boot -name "${1%.sig} -newer "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: thanks. To prevent warnings `-name` should be `-path` though.

Comment: +1 Can you explain the bit about the numbered positional parameter `$1`, which if I read yr one-liner well represents individual files put out by by `find /boot -type f -iname '*.sig'` ?   ---  But then I am not sure I understand the last bit `_ {} \;`. ---   `man find` on GNU findutils 4.6.0 was not terribly helpful in that respect.

Comment: You're right, the `{}` will be the first argument `"$1"` inside `sh -c`. This should be done like this to avoid code injection vulnerability by passing `{}` directly to the sh script. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely) for more details. Note, I changed `_`to `sh` ...