# Why does my find (+ sed) command work in the terminal but not in a makefile?

Tags: linux, sed, find, make

I have the following command:

```
find stdlib/main -type f -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed -e 's/stdlib\/main\///g' -e 's/\.q//g' -e 's/\//\./g' -e 's~^~/resource:\"{},~g' -e 's/$/\"/g'" \;
```

The goal is to find all files in `stdlib/main` (and subdirectories) and format them as such: `{filename},{filename-with-stdlibmain-removed-and-extension-removed-and-slashes-changed-to-dots}`

The command works perfectly when I run it myself. But I am trying to use it in a makefile as such:

```
STDLIB_RESOURCES=$(shell find stdlib/main -type f -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed -e 's/stdlib\/main\///g' -e 's/\.neo//g' -e 's/\//\./g' -e 's~^~/resource:\"{},~g' -e 's/$/\"/g'" \;)
```

When I run the makefile, I get one of these errors per file found:

```
sed: -e expression #5, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you missing? Probably the fact that you have quotes within quotes **within quotes**, and that `$(…)` is adding one more level of containment. A workaround would be to put the `sed` commands into a file and invoke it with ```sed -f```. I don’t immediately know how to do it in a self-contained way.

Comment: There's gotta be some way to do it in a self-contained way...

Comment: Try removing just the last sed expression (`-e 's/$/\"/g'`). This is the most likely to be tripping you up as it contains a `"` character. If that works, then you probably need to escape it better.

Comment: I get this when I do that: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'' /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Checked again and both of the last two sed expressions have `"` characters. Remove both of them. If that returns successfully, look at how to escape better. Your new error message definitely makes it look like the `"` that you removed was being interpreted before it could count in the sed command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you are missing is that `$` is a special character to make, and quoting is different in Make and the shell.

So for example

```
's/$/\"/g'
```

the `` pair protect everything inside them to the shell (and incidentally makes
the `\` unnecessary), but doesn't to make, so to make it looks like

```
 's/\"/g'
```

assuming you don't have a variable called `/` (which you could in make, but typically not in the shell).

The first thing to do is to replace `$` with `$$`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `{}` in an in-line script that you execute through `find` is a code injection vulnerability.  Don't do that.  The first argument to `sh -c` (the script) should be single quoted and the arguments to that script should be passed on its command line.

Instead, write the `find` command as something like the following (uses `bash` instead of `sh` to be able to use `${parameter//pattern/word}` in one place):

```
find stdlib/main -type f -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        string=${pathname#stdlib/main/} # delete initial path
        string=${string%.*}             # delete suffix after last dot
        string=${string////.}           # change slashes to dots

        # output:
        printf "resource:\"%s,%s\"\n" "$pathname" "$string"
    done' bash {} +
```

Instead of using `sed`, this uses parameter substitutions to modify the pathnames found by `find`.  The in-line `bash` script will be executed for batches of found files and will iterate over the pathnames in each batch. The `printf` would output the data transformed in the same way as what your `sed` command is doing (if I managed to decipher it correctly, it wasn't *just* what you described).

How you later cope with filenames containing double quotes and commas is another issue (the output string after `resource:` would potentially be difficult to parse).

It would be easiest to put the `find` command into a separate script and call that from GNU `make` in `$(shell ...)`, or you'll end up with something like

```
STDLIB_RESOURCES := $(shell     \
find stdlib/main -type f -exec bash -c '    \
    for p do                                \
        s=$${p\#stdlib/main/};              \
        s=$${s%.*};                         \
        s=$${s////.};                       \
        printf "resource:\"%s,%s\"\n" "$$p" "$$s"; \
    done' bash {} + )
```

in your Makefile (due to the way GNU `make` handles variables etc.)  Also note the `:=`.  You need this for the command to be executed immediately upon assigning to the variable, not every time the variable is accessed.

Related:

- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Congrats on becoming a moderator :) I put you as #1 when I voted.