# find -exec and increment counter / progress

Tags: command-line, find

TL;DR:

**Q: How to keep a counter in `find -exec` loop ?**

---

My use-case:

I need to move a lot of directories which are scattered around the place, so I do

```bsh
find . -type d -name "prefix_*" \
    -exec sh -c '
        new_path="/new/path/$(basedir "$1")";
        [ -d "$new_path" ] || mv "$1" "$new_path";
    ' find_sh {} \;
```

(The real command is more complex, as I read some metadata for the constitution of `/new/path`. Anyways, I do not want to argue about the command itself, it's not part of the question, just the use-case).

It works just fine, but it takes quite a while and I want to keep track of the progress.

So I added a counter writing to a file:

```bsh
i=$(cat ~/find_increment || echo 0);
echo $((i+1)) | tee ~/find_increment;
```

That also works just fine, but it feels like a **really** bad idea having some 100.000 disk read and write operations.

I thought about writing to `ramdisk` instead of disk, but I don't have that option in the environment I need to perform that task.

Is there a better way to keep a counter between `-exec` runs ?

Comment: What is `find_sh` in the first command? So basically you want to know the number of new paths created?

Comment: Your 100,000 disk operations won’t result in 100,000 reads from or writes to the hardware; most operations will take place in the cache.

Comment: no i want to keep progress how much was done while doing it. To print percentage or so. `find_sh` is just the way [how to use sh -c safely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely).

Comment: hmmmm .... I could probably use `/dev/shm` ... ?!

Comment: @RoVo that would be an option, but what I’m saying is that there’s no need to worry about it, the kernel will take care of reducing the number of real disk operations. You can try it yourself by issuing 100,000 writes and watching the real block device activity (using `blktrace`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a pure `find` command you could combine `find` with a `while read` loop or GNU `parallel`. Both are likely to be faster than `find`'s `-exec` since you don't start a new shell for every path found by `find`.

#### Solution Using GNU Parallel

GNU `parallel` has the following benefits compared to `while read`:

- Easier to get right. No `IFS=` and `-r` needed.
- Built-in job number variable `{#}`.
  For more handy replacement strings have a look at [the tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Replacement-strings).
- Easy to parallelize if needed.
  Remove the `-j1` and you have as many workers as cores by default.

```
script='
    echo Processing job number {#}
    new_path="/new/path/$(basedir {})"
    [ -d "$new_path" ] || mv {} "$new_path"
'
find … -print0 | parallel -0 -j1 "$script"
```

The `{}` is replaced by `parallel` by the correctly quoted entry read from `stdin`. Do not quote `{}` again.

`parallel` executes the script with the same shell from which you started it. If you started `parallel` in `bash` you can use `bash` features in the script.

#### Solution Using While Read

```
find … -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' old_path; do
    echo Processing job number "$((++job))"
    new_path="/new/path/$(basedir "$old_path")"
    [ -d "$new_path" ] || mv "$old_path" "$new_path"
done
```

Comment: This works very well and will be most of the times the way to go for me. Unfortunately, `parallel` is not available in the environment I need to use it right now :-(.

Comment: Glad I could help. I added the `while read` version for use in your environment without `parallel`.

Comment: @RoVo can you elaborate on why GNU Parallel is not available? Is it covered in: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: @Socowi Instead of putting the script in a variable (which can result in quoting madness), consider using a bash function instead. Just remember to `export -f` the function before using it in GNU Parallel.

Comment: To see progress also checkout `--bar`. In this case I think it might be more useful than the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

If available, store the counter in `/dev/shm/` to prevent disk writes.

=> Use `/dev/shm/find_increment` instead of `~/find_increment`.