# Get filenames and write them on place of previous namespace

Tags: bash, sed, find, rename

I have hundreds of sources codes files. I want to rename namespace according to the filenames path. Of course slashes must be replace by dots.

I have tried with *find -exec* but I failed to get the filename inside *sed* to replace the current namespace with the path.

```
find -type f -iname *.cs  -exec  sh -c 'x="{}"; sed -E "s/\//./; s/(namespace.Project).+/\1.$x/" {}' \;
```

But I get

> sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Please view https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely

Comment: @pLumo please post that as an answer. When you post answers as comments, the question remains marked as unanswered. You also circumvent the normal working of the site since your answer can't be voted on.

Comment: @jdoe, please [edit] your question and show us a few examples of the output of `find -type f -iname *.cs` and then show us what you want to do to those files. Do you actually want to rename them? Do you just want to print them? Do you only want to change `/` to `.`? We can't really help unless you show us exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The first `sed` command (`s/\//./`) will replace all slashes with a dot in the file **content**, not in the file name.

The second `sed` command (`s/(namespace.Project).+/\1.$x/`) will add `$x` (the still unaltered file path) to the namespace. This produces an error in `sed` because it contains unescaped slashes which are interpreted by `sed`.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed).

---

Also, please read on [how to use `find -exec sh -c` safely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely). Adding `{}` directly to the bash content is a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

well I find my way… with bash variables.
Something like this:

```
for i in `find -type f -iname *.cs`; do j=$(echo $i|sed -E 's/\.\//namespace Project\//g;s/\//./g; s/(\.[[:alnum:]]*\.cs$)//g'); sed -i -E "s/(namespace Project.+)/$j/g" $i ; done;
```