# Find exec - Why {} can't be used as the output file name?

Tags: find, gzip

I tried this command to compress all the css files in all subdirectories.

```
find . -iname "*.css*" -exec gzip -c '{}' > '{}'.gz  \;
```

But it only creates a {}.gz file. I ended up using this:

```
find . -iname "*.css" -exec sh -c "gzip -c '{}' > '{}'.gz"  \;
```

which works well.

The question is why the first one didn't work and second one did?

Note: I could easily use gzip -k switch to keep the source files, but gzip on CentOS 7 does not support it.

Comment: Do not use `{}` inside `sh -c`. Please [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about when and by which shell the command gets interpreted. In the first, your command line shell interprets the >, making a local file before find even starts. In the second, the subshell does, after find replaces the {}, so it works as expected.