# find: unknown predicate `-p'

Tags: find, quoting

```
find /log/ -mtime -31 -type f -name ""*data.txt"" -printf ""cp -p %p /Backup/%Td/\n"" | sh
```

I am trying to set up this command in a cron job and it's complaining about `unknown predicate -p`. Not really a cron issue, looks like a shell-scripting problem.

How can I fix this? Quoting `-p` doesn't help.

Comment: Why is everything double double quoted?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to nest double-quotes inside double-quotes; that doesn't work. In general, trying to construct command strings and then execute them isn't safe. See [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely) for a much better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Since the quoted strings are double...double quoted they are actually not quoted at all.

You have:

```
find /log/ -mtime -31 -type f -name ""*data.txt"" -printf ""cp -p %p /Backup/%Td/\n"" | sh
```

This should be:

```
find /log/ -mtime -31 -type f -name "*data.txt" -printf "cp -p %p /Backup/%Td/\n" | sh
```

You probably shouldn't do this though.  You should use `find -exec` to copy these files.

Comment: @steeldriver - exactly! I need the file modification times in order to copy them into appropriate directories and I could not find a way to combine `-exec` with what I am trying to do. That's why I am trying to use `-printf`. Let me try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: so x-y problem.

Comment: @steeldriver what if someone creates a file named `/log/path/to/." -r foo; echo rm -fr ~; : "data.txt`? how would your quoting help?

Comment: @mosvy fair point

Comment: @GA_train A better idea would probably be: `find /log/ -mtime -31 -type f -name '*data.txt' -printf '%Td %p\0' | xargs -0 sh -c 'for a; do printf "{%s} " cp -p "${a#* }" "/Backup/${a%% *}/"; echo; done' sh` (untested; remove the `printf "{%s} "` and the `echo;` if right).