# xargs with multiple commands and max-args

Tags: xargs

I have a program that requires arbitrary number of files. It works like

```
./code output.txt file1 file2 file3
```

And I have thousand of input files for it: file1, file2, ..., file1000.

However

I can split the input files in different sets. For example, combining 2 consequent input files:

```
./code output.txt file1 file2
./code output.txt file3 file4
...
```

(where output.txt is appending during each call of the code)
Or, combining 3 consequent input files:

```
./code output.txt file1 file2 file3
./code output.txt file4 file5 file6
...
```

I found that `xargs` can be helpful for it:

```
ls file* | xargs -n3
```

The input is really splits into groups of three files.

But when I use xargs with more commands with 'I' option it passes to ./code just file1:

```
ls file* | xargs -n3 -I {} sh -c './code output.txt {}; command2; command3'
```

Could you please point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't use `ls` in a pipe. Note `echo file*` (or better `print`) would do the same. It is not `ls` that does the expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `{}` as part of the `sh -c` script text (the issue is similar to the one described in the accepted answer to [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)).

Instead:

```sh
printf '%s\n' file* | xargs -n 3 sh -c './code output.txt "$@"; command2; command3' sh
```

This would work as long as no filename contains newlines.  If your `xargs` has the non-standard `-0` option (most common implementation have), the following would also work for filenames with newlines:

```sh
printf '%s\0' file* | xargs -0 -n 3 sh -c './code output.txt "$@"; command2; command3' sh
```

The `"$@"` (the quotes are *important*) will be expanded to the list of the positional parameters inside the `sh -c` script.  These are the filenames given to the script by `xargs`.  The seemingly useless `sh` at the very end will be put into `$0` in the `sh -c` script and used in any error messages that that shell produces (it is not part of `"$@"`).

In the `zsh` shell (but not in e.g. `bash` or `sh`), you could instead do

```
for name1 name2 name3 in file*; do
    ./code output.txt $name1 $name2 $name3
    command2
    command3
done
```

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Comment: What about `printf '%s\0' file* | xargs -0 -n 3 sh -c ...`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yeah. Added.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. The code you provided works perfectly.