# piping output of find command

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find

Further to my query posted -
[Using find with sh - command not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577532/using-find-with-sh-command-not-working#577537)

Based on the o/p of the below command I need to update the permission to 777 for each of the files that are listed.

```
find . -type f -name '*FW*' -exec grep -iEq 'chmod.*archive|archive.*chmod' {} \; -ls
```

Is there any way that we can pipe the output to `chmod` and update file permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `-exec` to `find` to execute `chmod` on the files. Remove the `-ls` if you don't need it:

```
find . -type f -name '*FW*' -exec grep -iEq 'chmod.*archive|archive.*chmod' {} \;\
  -ls -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `-exec` at the end to update the permissions on the files that pass the preceding tests, [like Freddy shows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577559/116858), or you may combine the `grep` and `chmod` in an inline `sh -c` script:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*FW*' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if grep -q -i -e "chmod.*archive" -e "archive.*chmod" "$pathname"
        then
            chmod 777 "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This would use `find` as a sort of a generator of pathnames for the loop in the `sh -c` script.

This loop takes all pathnames given to the inline script, tests each one with `grep`, and if the pattern matches in a file, that file gets its permissions (possibly) updated.

---

In `bash`, you may, instead of generating the pathnames by `find`, use a filename globbing pattern:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

for pathname in ./**/*FW*; do
    if [ -f "$pathname" ] && grep -q -i -e 'chmod.*archive' -e 'archive.*chmod' "$pathname"
    then
        chmod 777 "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

The only visible difference here is that this would also process symbolic links that match the pattern.

The `globstar` shell option enables the `**` pattern that matches recursively into subdirectories.  The `nullglob` shell option makes non-matching patterns disappear instead of remaining unexpanded. The `dotglob` shell option makes patterns match hidden names.

In the `zsh` shell, this may be shortened to

```bsh
for pathname in ./**/*FW*(.ND); do
    if grep -q -i -e 'chmod.*archive' -e 'archive.*chmod' $pathname
    then
        chmod 777 $pathname
    fi
done
```

... where the `.`, `N` and `D` corresponds to the `-f` test (but won't match symbolic links), setting `nullglob` and setting `dotglob` in `bash`, in turn.