# Using find with sh command not working - further queries

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find

Further to the earlier query posted 
[Using find with sh - command not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577532/using-find-with-sh-command-not-working#577537)

```
find . -type f -name '*FW*' -exec grep -iEq 'chmod.*archive|archive.*chmod' {} \; -ls
```

This cmd was not able to find the files when "archive" or "chmod" text is found in multiple lines. However it is able  to scan the files , when  "chmod" and "archive" text is found in the same line.

So tried with this command , but it doesnt give the desired o/p

```
1> find . -type f -name '*FW*' -exec grep -iEq 'chmod.*' {} \; -ls -exec grep -iEq '.*archive.*' {} +
```

Why this cmd doesnt give the desired o/p?

TRied with this command , it gives the result as expected but it fails intermittently with this error "find: 'pcregrep' terminated by signal 11'

```
2> find . -type f -name '*FW*' -exec pcregrep -qM 'chmod.*(\n|.)*archive.*' {} \; -ls
```

Why it is failing with the error?

Comment: I am trying to make sense of your question: You said "text is found in multiple lines". Did you mean "text is found on different lines"?

Answer (score 1):

Your second command in the question is not giving you the correct output because the ordering of the tests that you use with `find` is important.  The command will only output results for files that contain the `chmod` string because the other `grep` command is run *after* `-ls` (and does not produce output).

You want to find files that contain both the strings `chmod` and `archive`.

```
find . -type f -name '*FW*' \
    -exec grep -Fiq chmod {} \; \
    -exec grep -Fiq archive {} \; -ls
```

This calls `grep -Fiq chmod` on all files that has `FW` in their name, and then `grep -Fiq archive` on those that the first `grep` found a match in. If the second `grep` also found something, the `-ls` takes effect.

Comment: Finding files that doesn't contain `chmod` nor `archive` in the whole file might be as short as using this command: `grep -Eirzvl 'chmod|archive'`. Of course, find and grep will walk the directory in diferent ways, but that doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Comment: @Isaac The task is to find files that contain _both_ of the strings. If you wanted to find files that contain _neither_, you would use `! -exec grep -Fiq -e 'chmod' -e 'archive' {} \;` with `find`. With `grep -v` you'd get files with lines that does not contain the pattern, not files that does not contain the pattern (at all).

Comment: Yes, I just realize that the command as written doesn't work. Back to the drawing board ....