# In find -exec, how to substitue current file by {}?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I want to find all files the are not owned by me (that is, having no permission to modify it). I have tried

```
find . -exec if [[ ! -O {} ]]; then echo {}; fi ;
```

But if I put the whole command after `-exec` in quotes, like this:

```
find . -exec 'if [[ ! -O {} ]]; then echo {}; fi' \;
```

Neither that work, because the reference to the current file `{}` is in quotes and therefor does not expand to the file.

The problem is, I do not know how to embed the `{}` as current file to more complex `-exec` then simply for example `find . -exec grep smf {} \;` (that uses the `{}` only once). How to use `-exec` option in find in commands, where you reference to the current file more then once ? (That is using `{}` more time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because the utility that you ask `find` to run, `if`, does not exist (it's a keyword in the shell syntax).

The `-O` test is true if the argument is a file that is owned by the current user. The same test can be done in `find` itself with `-user "$USER"` (assuming `$USER` expands to the current user):

```
find . -type f ! -user "$USER"
```

You could also use `test -O` if your external `test` utility supports that non-standard test (check `man test`):

```
find . -type f ! -exec test -O {} \; -print
```

If you still wanted or needed to use the `-O` test built into the `bash` shell, then you would have to spawn a `bash` shell to perform the test:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ ! -O "$1" ]]' bash {} \; -print
```

This starts one inline `bash -c` script for each found file that runs the test on its first argument (`$1`).  The argument is passed on the command line of the script by `find` (the `bash` string before `{}` will be placed in `$0` inside the script, and will be used by that shell for error messages).  If the test is true (the file is not owned by you), `-print` takes effect and prints the pathname of the file.

You can do this a bit more efficiently with

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        [[ ! -O "$pathname" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    done' bash {} +
```

This is more efficient since it passes batches of found pathnames to the `bash -c` script.

... but using `-user "$USER"` would be the better option.

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)

Comment: Can you more elaborate the latter example? Why is there second spawn of bash for `{}`?

Comment: @Herdsman There is not. The `bash` just before `{}` is a string that is placed in `$0`. It is _only_ used by the `bash -c` script if it needs to print any error messages.