# How to make a text file in every subdirectory so that the text file contains name of the directory

Tags: linux, directory

I have 5 empty directories:

```
[X]$ ls
dir_1  dir_2  dir_3  dir_4  dir_5
```

How can I make a text file in every one of these directories so that the text file would contain the name of the directory it is in? So for example, `dir_1` would contain text file `file_1.txt` and this text file has text `dir_1` in it, `dir_2` contains text file `file_2.txt` that has text `dir_2` in it and so on.

I searched for information but I couldn't figure this out. I started to learn linux very recently. Do I have to do something like:

```
find . -type d -exec touch (something?)
```

And is it possible to do this with for loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for d in dir_*; do
    printf "%s\n" "$d" > "$d/file_${d##*_}.txt"
done
```

- `$d` expands to each directory name.
- `${d##*_}` expands to the trailing number in the directory name, because it removes everything up to the last underscore from `$d`. Read more in Parameter Expansion section in [BASH manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) or [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).
- `printf "%s\n" "$d" > "$d/file_${d##*_}.txt"` writes the directory name to a txt file in that directory.

With an one-liner:

```
for d in dir_*; do printf "%s\n" "$d" > "$d/file_${d##*_}.txt"; done
```

I have favored `printf` to `echo` because there are special cases that are handled correctly by the former but not by the latter, although in the particular case presented `echo` would not arise problems. Find more in [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803).

---

If you need to avoid non-directories that also begin with `dir_`, option 1 is to add the `[ -d "$d" ] &&` test right before `printf` statement in the script above. Option 2 is to use `dir_*/` so that only directories are matched:

```
for d in dir_*/; do
    dirn=${d%%/}
    printf "%s\n" "$dirn" > "${d}file_${dirn##*_}.txt"
done
```

Comment: You would need to use `dir_*/` as the pattern to avoid non-directories, such as `dir_listfile`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you for pointing that, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name 'dir_[0-9]*'  -type d -execdir bash -c 'name=$0;printf "${name##*/}\n" > "$name/file_${name##*_}.txt"' '{}' \;
```

Execute multiple commands from find result using `-execdir`

`name=$0;` => store each directory name in $name variable and process it.

Comment: Sorry for being a pest here, but: 1) `*` isn't the only special character in `dir_[0-9]\*`, the full pattern should be quoted (`'dir_[0-9]*'`): as it is, it breaks if the current directory contains a directory named e.g. `dir_1*` (with a literal `*`). 2) Embedding `{}` in shell code is an [injection vulnerability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/315749) - it'd be better to use `bash -c 'name="$1"; ...' sh '{}' \;` (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) 3) please refer to [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588342/how-to-make-a-text-file-in-every-subdirectory-so-that-the-text-file-contains-nam#comment1096163_588344) to the other answer about why `printf` should be preferred to `echo`. 4) Expansions should always be quoted, unless you really need them not to be: think about people who modifies your script to make it also find files whose name may contain spaces.

Comment: no problem , explanation about small things helps a lot ...your points are correct , also i would add that instead of `bash -c 'name="$1"; ...' sh '{}' \;` we can use `bash -c 'name="$1"; ...' '{}' \;`  just without  `sh` ....will edit my answer...

Comment: The first argument after `bash -c 'name="$1"; ...'` is used as the name for the script and is assigned to `$0`, you _need_ some string there, before `'{}'`. Otherwise `$1` just remains unset (as you have seen). I'd also use `"$name/file_${name##*_}.txt"` (in double quotes). And give `'%s\n'` as a format string to `printf`.

Comment: yes , positional arguments starts with $0 , so i preferred that...thanks...

Comment: What I meant is: `find . -name 'dir_[0-9]*' -type d -execdir bash -c 'name=$1; printf "%s\n" "${name##*/}" > "$name/file_${name##*_}.txt"' mybash '{}' \;`. Please have a look at it - I'm not further bothering you, thank you for your patience.