# need script to rename files replacing double space with single space

Tags: shell-script, sed, xargs, whitespace

Can someone help me figure out how to remove double spaces from directory names?

I'm using a service which gives me a directory structure of files whose names contain spaces.
Sometimes the directory names contain double spaces, and some of my home grown scripts can't handle it.

I'd like a shell command combination which will rename the directories removing double space.  Sort of like `sed 's/  / /g'`.

Luckily there are no children directories whose parents also need to be renamed.

I can find the candidates like this

```bsh
sh> find ~/Downloads/Scala_Intro -name '*  *' -print 
/Users/jimka/Downloads/Scala_Intro/SCALAIN_E-Running Average-362/Edward  Cacioppo_2973_assignsubmission_file_
/Users/jimka/Downloads/Scala_Intro/SCALAIN_E-Implement histogram-3169/Edward  Cacioppo_3102_assignsubmission_file_
```

But when I try to use `xargs` to manipulate this sequence of lines, `xargs` substitution seems to remove the double space.  Thus I cannot generate the command line `mv old-name new-name`

```bsh
sh> find ~/Downloads/Scala_Intro -name '*  *' -print | xargs -I % echo %
/Users/jimka/Downloads/Scala_Intro/SCALAIN_E-Running Average-362/Edward Cacioppo_2973_assignsubmission_file_
/Users/jimka/Downloads/Scala_Intro/SCALAIN_E-Implement histogram-3169/Edward Cacioppo_3102_assignsubmission_file_
```

I was trying something like the following, but it doesn't work.

```bsh
sh> find ~/Downloads/Scala_Intro -name '*  *' -print | xargs -p -I % mv  "%" `echo "%" | sed 's/  / /g'`
mv /Users/jimka/Downloads/Scala_Intro/SCALAIN_E-Running Average-362/Edward Cacioppo_2973_assignsubmission_file_ /Users/jimka/Downloads/Scala_Intro/SCALAIN_E-Running Average-362/Edward Cacioppo_2973_assignsubmission_file_?...
```

Notice when xargs asks whether to execute the `mv` command, the doubled space has already been converted to a single space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `xargs` and `mv`, I would prefer `rename` tool:

Depending on which rename tool you have:

```
find ~/Downloads/Scala_Intro -name '*  *' -exec rename -n '  ' ' ' {} +
```

or

```
find ~/Downloads/Scala_Intro -name '*  *' -exec rename -n 's/  / /' {} +
```

(Remove `-n` option (dry-run) to actually perform the renaming if you're happy with the output)

---

Or if you want to stick using `mv` (no `xargs` needed, `find -exec` will do):

```
find ~/Downloads/Scala_Intro -name '*  *' -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1//  / }"' find-sh {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what find-sh is?  Is that a bash-ism?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/236063 > "*You should use something relevant there (like sh or find-sh)*"