# find and execute bsub < for multiple files

Tags: linux, find

I intend to find `*.lsf` following the current `/subdirectories` and execute `bsub<*.lsf` for all the find files.
I tried:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.lsf" -exec bsub < \;
```

The part `find ./ -type f -name "*.lsf"` works fine. However, the execute part has problems.

Can anyone helps figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there with your first attempt. What you need to do is to invoke a shell to parse the `<` redirection operator

```
find -name '*.lsf' -exec bash -c 'bsub <"$1"' _ {} \;
```

However, this isn't very efficient as you are now starting a shell for every matched file. Invoke the shell as few times as possible and use a loop to process multiple files at once

```
find -name '*.lsf' -exec bash -c 'for i in "$@"; do bsub <"$i"; done' _ {} +
```

Both of these are filename-safe (i.e. they handle whitespace and non-printing/semi-printing characters in file names).

Comment: thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could work with `xargs`:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.lsf" | xargs bsub
```

In fact, you could shorten the hole thing to:

```
find *.lsf | xargs bsub
```

Comment: Tested on the cluster I use.

Edit: Removed replacement string option and redirection character.

Comment: It showed: "-bash: {}: No such file or directory". Can you explain a little of xargs -I {} ?

Comment: You did not test that. It can't work, as the `<` and it right hand side operator, will be evaluated before the programs are executed.

Comment: You are right. I did not test it. Depending a bit on what `bsub` does, you can probably leave the `<`.

Comment: `xargs -I {}` tells xargs to replace the string `{}` with what it gets from standard input. In this case stdin is the pipe `|`. Which redirects the standard output from `find`. TThe replacement string does not have to be `{}`, it can be anything you chose. `{}` is just common. This is all in the man pages

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs`, in a way that works. (Note as @KamilMaciorowski said, this is unsafe.)

```
find . -type f -iname "*.lsf" | xargs -I {} bash -c 'cat < {}'
```

Then fixing for file-names spaces etc

```
find . -type f -iname "*.lsf" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'cat < {}'
```

I tested with `cat`. You will have to replace with your command

Comment: [Do not embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes I agree. Can you provide an alternate solution?

Comment: The answer I linked to provides a safe way: `… bash -c 'cat < "$1"' bash {}`