# How do I set a value when running find command?

Tags: shell-script, find, date, variable, timestamps

I'm running a long string of -exec commands, and I want to pull a timestamp from the beginning of the run to use as a value for subsequent commands. Is this possible? Something like:

```
find . -exec NOW=$(date +%s) {} \; -exec echo $NOW."$0" {} \;
find . -exec set NOW=$(date +%s) {} \; -exec echo $NOW."$0" {} \;
find . -exec export NOW=$(date +%s) {} \; -exec echo $NOW."$0" {} \;
```

Those don't seem to work, but if I just use $(date +%s) instead of setting the value, I get inconsistent timestamps because each subsequent -exec is happening later in time.

What I want is a different timestamp to use for each file. For example, modifying someones suggestion, this may show my intent better:

```
find . -exec sh -c '
    NOW=$(date +%s); for f in "$@"; do echo "$NOW  $f First Output"; sleep 3; echo "$NOW $f Second Output"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

That command doesn't do what I want, but shows that the delay when acting on the first file should not change the timestamp, should output the timestamp and file name, sleep 3, and output the SAME timestamp for that file. Then I want it to create a new timestamp to use with the next file.

Comment: You cannot pass variables between different `-exec` commands, but you can write the data to a file.

Comment: Please explain in your question what you want to achieve. Using an example may be helpful to understand your requirements.

Comment: I think I got it now, and my answer is not valid for this, removed

Comment: Is there a guarantee that your `-exec` commands will take longer than a second? If the commands run faster you will get the same timestamp for several files.

Answer (score 4):

Use only one `-exec` together with `sh -c`:

```bsh
find . -exec sh -c '
    NOW=$(date +%s);
    echo "$NOW $1 First Output";
    sleep 3;
    echo "$NOW $1 Second Output";
' find-sh {} \;
```

---

As an alternative, If you for whatever reason want to stick to chained `-exec`s, you could use a temp file, but then you need `sh -c` whenever you read that temp file:

```bsh
find . \
  -exec sh -c 'date +%s > /tmp/now' \; \
  -exec sh -c 'echo "$(cat /tmp/now) $1 First Output"' find-sh {} \; \
  -exec sleep 3 \; \
  -exec sh -c 'echo "$(cat /tmp/now) $1 Second Output"' find-sh {} \;
```

The following `-exec` won't work, because the shell will evaluate the `$(..)` part before the `find` run:

```
-exec echo "$(cat /tmp/now) {} First Output" \;
```

---

PS:

You may ask, where is this `find-sh` from `-exec sh -c '...' find-sh {}` coming from. [Here is the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/236063).

Comment: You got it! Thank you. I'm going to test that a bit, but I think that works.

Comment: Note that you will probably get the same time stamp for several files if you remove the `sleep` command, i.e. if the real command runs fast.

Answer (score 3):

Set `NOW` for each file anew, i.e. *inside* the `for` loop:

```
find . -exec sh -c '
   for f do
      NOW=$(date +%s)
      echo "$NOW  $f First Output"
      sleep 3
      echo "$NOW $f Second Output"
   done
' find-sh {} +
```

Comment: @pLumo, `+` and the loop avoids forking a shell for every file.

Comment: That is indeed true -_-

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what you want to do but if you want a value of `$NOW` that is updated to the current epoch time at the point each file is processed you could use `zsh` and its `$EPOCHSECONDS` variable (or `$EPOCHREALTIME` if you want the nanoseconds as well) in the `zsh/datetime` module (or `${(%):-%D{%s}}` without `zsh/datetime`, though that's less legible):

```
find . -exec zsh -c '
  zmodload zsh/datetime
  typeset -F SECONDS # make it float
  for file do
    start_time=$EPOCHSECONDS SECONDS=0
    print -r $start_time processing $file

    processing $file

    end_time=$EPOCHSECONDS duration=$SECONDS
    print start=$start_time end=$end_time duration=$SECONDS
  done' zsh {} +
```

Or since `zsh` can do `find`'s job with its recursive globs:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

zmodload zsh/datetime
typeset -F SECONDS # make it float.

for file (./**/*(ND)) {
  start_time=$EPOCHSECONDS SECONDS=0
  print -r $start_time processing $file

  processing $file

  end_time=$EPOCHSECONDS duration=$SECONDS
  print start=$start_time end=$end_time duration=$SECONDS
}
```

In the `bash` shell, you can get the equivalent of `start_time=$EPOCHSECONDS` with `printf -v start_time '%(%s)T'`.