# -exec to xargs conversion in find command

Tags: linux, find, xargs

I'm using the below command in my script to perform a `dos2unix` operation on the files which I copy from Windows to Linux. There are many files, so it takes a considerable amount of time to perform this operation.

I searched on the internet for optimizing this find and found that we can use `xargs` with `find` instead of `-exec` to increase the performance, but I'm struggling to convert the below one to use with `xargs`:

```
find /path_to_files/ -exec bash -c 'dos2unix -k -n "{}" tmp_file && mv tmp_file "{}"' \;
```

Comment: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script in `~/bin` to process a list of files, call it `doit`, containing

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $# -ne 0 ]] ; do
    thisfile="$1"
    shift
    dos2unix -k -n "$thisfile" tmp_file
    mv tmp_file "$thisfile"
done
```

Then,

```
chmod +x ~/bin/doit
```

And finally,

```
find /path/to/files -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r $HOME/bin/doit
```

Read `man find xargs bash`.

Comment: @waltinator Instead of the `while` loop with assignment and `shift`, you could simply write `for thisfile in "$@"; do ...` or even shorter `for thisfile; do ...` – the latter automatically loops over the command line arguments.

Comment: @Ashish This should work for a million files. xargs knows how many args the command line can contain. It reruns the doit command as many times as it needs for the total number of files.

Answer (score 8):

It is actually much more simple. You do not need to invoke a shell nor use `mv` because `dos2unix` already modifies the target file if you do not give it the `-n` flag.

```
find /path_to_files -type f -exec dos2unix -k -q -- {} +
```

`-type f` so that find only searches for regular files, not directories. `-q` flag is given to `dos2unix` so that it does not write informational messages to stdout. And we use `{} +` instead of `{} \;` so that find does not invoke one `dos2unix` process for each file found, instead it gives so much files as it can as arguments (`dos2unix file1 file2 file3 ...`).

Xargs would just be one extra process and thus one extra time penalty. Avoid invoking new processes whenever you can.