# How to copy a file and change destination file permission in one step?

Tags: permissions, cp, file-copy

I am writing a shell script to do some complex task which is repetitive in nature.
To simplify the problem statement, the last step in my complex task is to copy a file from a particular path (which is found based on some complex step) to a pre-defined destination path. And the file that gets copied will have the permission as 600. I want this to be changed to 644.

I am looking at an option where in I can instruct the system to copy that file and change the permission all in one command. Something like -
`cp -<some_flag> 644 <source_path> <destination_path>`

You may say, I can change the permission of the file once it is copied in a 2 step process. However, there is problem with that as well. Reason being, the source path is obtained as an output of another command. So I get the absolute path for the file and not just the file name to write my script to call `chmod` with a name.

My command last segment looks like -
`...| xargs -I {} cp {} /my/destination/path/`

So I dont know the name of the file to call `chmod` after the copy

Comment: Does your system provide the `install` command?

Comment: No. I can't install it either. We don't have necessary permission to install any additional packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the `chmod` in your `xargs` call:

```
...|  xargs sh -c 'for file; do 
                      cp -- "$file" /my/destination/path/ && 
                        chmod 700 /my/destination/path/"$file"; 
                    done' sh
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/22222 for more on the specific format used.

Note that if your input to `xargs` is a full path and not a file name in the local directory, you will need to use `${file##*/}` to get the file
name only:

```
...|  xargs sh -c 'for file; do 
                  cp -- "$file" /my/destination/path/ && 
                    chmod 700 /my/destination/path/"${file##*/}"; 
                done' sh
```

Comment: @steeldriver ah yes, good point. Depends on what the OP is doing of course, and we have no information to go on.

Comment: Yeah, it worked with the modification what @steeldriver mentioned. Thanks both.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Since we now know it's needed, I added steeldriver's improvement to the answer.