# Linux show files in directory larger than 1 GB and show size

Tags: command-line, find, disk-usage

I am trying to find a command that displays files larger than 1 GB and displays those files ordered by size. I have tried `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -size +1G -print0 |xargs -0 du -h |sort -rh` but for some reason this displays files of size that are not greater than 1 GB.
For example this is in the output `1.0K    ./<repo>/.git/info`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least two possible causes:

1. Maybe your `find` prints nothing. In this case `xargs` runs `du -h` which is equivalent to `du -h .`. Investigate [`--no-run-if-empty`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html#OPTIONS) option of GNU `xargs`. Or better get used to `find … -exec …` instead of `find … | xargs …`. Like this:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -size +1G -exec du -h {} + | sort -rh
   ```
2. `find -size` tests (almost) what [`du --apparent-size`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html#DESCRIPTION) shows, while `du` without this option may greatly disagree, especially when the file is sparse. The option is not portable.

I think in your case the first cause is the culprit. Note `./<repo>/.git/info` couldn't come from `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f` because its depth is 3. This means `du` operated recursively on some directory.

Comment: Brilliant! ```find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -size +1G -exec du -h {} + | sort -rh``` works as expected. Are there any implications I should be aware of when running ```find ... -exec``` instead of ```find … | xargs …```? New to this area, appreciate any knowledge.

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove I find `find -exec` more straightforward than `find … | xargs …` because `xargs` has its options and quirks. Read good answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/108618) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/108618).

Comment: thanks! this has been helpful