# Bash script (triggered on Transmission torrent download) not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, transmission

I'm trying to create a bash script that is executed by Transmission when a torrent file is downloaded, and automatically extract `*.rar` files into the same directory.

#### This is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "------" >> /tmp/transmission.log
date >> /tmp/transmission.log 
echo "$TR_TORRENT_DIR" >> /tmp/transmission.log
echo "$TR_TORRENT_NAME" >> /tmp/transmission.log
echo "Trying to extract: $TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" >> /tmp/transmission.log
find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec /usr/local/bin/bash -c 'cd "{}" && find . -name "*.rar" | xargs /usr/local/bin/7z x' \; &>> /tmp/transmission.log
```

The script is triggered, and everything looks fine, but there is no log output from the last line of the script, and the rar is never extracted. The script has `chmod +x`.

#### `/tmp/transmission.log` shows

```
------
Wed Feb 10 12:23:40 CET 2021
/Volumes/TV
My.File.720p.HDTV.x264-FILE
Trying to extract: /Volumes/TV/My.File.720p.HDTV.x264-FILE
```

#### What I've tried

If I manually set `export TR_TORRENT_NAME=...` and `export TR_TORRENT_DIR=...` in Terminal and run the command from the last line of the script, then the file is actually extracted properly.

**What could be going on here? How can I debug this issue further?**

Comment: Side issue: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618)

Comment: Is `/Volumes/TV/My.File.720p.HDTV.x264-FILE` a directory or a file? The name indicates a file; if so, `find /Volumes/TV/My.File.720p.HDTV.x264-FILE -type d ...` doesn't find anything, therefore no output is generated.

Comment: The nested `find` is overly complex. `find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.rar" -execdir 7z {} \;` (not sure if this is correct) executes the 7z command in the directory where the rar file resides.

Comment: It's a folder, sorry about the confusion! Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that when I'm in front of my office server. :) I think 7z have to be executed in the same dir, som that is a good suggestion. :)

Comment: Tested now, it had the same problems. Worked directly in the Terminal, but didn't work from the transmission script. But I figured it out, the issue was that Terminal is using `/bin/zsh` while the script was using `/bin/bash`.  But your simpler solution still didn't work properly from the script, so I have to use this complex line: `find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec /bin/zsh -c 'cd "{}" && find . -name "*.rar" | xargs /usr/local/bin/7z x' \; &>> /Users/user/Library/Logs/transmission.log`. If you know what could be wrong, I would love to use the simple version.

Comment: Your's work if I specify absolute path to `7z` like `/usr/local/bin/7z`. Anyone know why? When checking, Terminal is using `zsh` and `$PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin`. Maybe `find`'s `-execdir` is executing in a different environment?

Comment: @eivindml Is `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH` for both `bash` and `zsh`?

Comment: No, I probably haven't added that to Bash (not in front of that computer). So `find` maybe uses bash even though the script file uses `#!/bin/zsh`?