# Pipe globs to ls

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, ls, cat

Contents of file `filelist`:

```
/some/path/*.txt
/other/path/*.dat
/third/path/example.doc
```

I want to list those files, so I do:

```bsh
cat filelist | xargs ls
```

But instead of expanding those globs, I get:

> ```
> ls: cannot access '/some/path/*.txt': No such file or directory  
> ls: cannot access '/other/path/*.dat': No such file or directory  
> /third/path/example.doc
> ```

Comment: The shell expands globbed filenames. `xargs` is not a shell: it just passes the file contents as args to `ls`, as plain text. I wondered where the stars had gone, but this site uses them as markup. which is why everything from txt is in italic.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yeah that's a site rendering problem. Thanks for explaining the subtlety of xargs... any idea what I should do instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shells expand globs. Here, that's one of the very rare cases where the implicit split+glob operator invoked upon unquoted command substitution in Bourne-like shells other than zsh can be useful:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline only
set +o noglob # make sure globbing is not disabled
ls -ld -- $(cat filelist) # split+glob
```

In `zsh`, you'd do:

```
ls -ld -- ${(f)~"$(<filelist)"}
```

Where `f` is the parameter expansion flag to split on linefeeds, and `~` *requests* globbing which is otherwise not done by default upon parameter expansion nor command substitution.

Note that if the list of matching files is large, you can run into an *Argument list too long* error (a limitation of the `execve()` system call on most systems), which `xargs` would have otherwise worked around. In `zsh`, you can use `zargs` instead:

```
autoload zargs
zargs --eof= -- ${(f)~"$(<filelist)"} '' ls -ld --
```

Where `zargs` will split the list and run `ls` several times to avoid the limit as necessary as `xargs` would.

Or you could pass the list to a command that is builtin (so doesn't involve the `execve()` system call):

To just print the list of files:

```
print -rC1 -- ${(f)~"$(<filelist)"}
```

Or to feed it to `xargs` NUL-delimited:

```
print -rNC1 -- ${(f)~"$(<filelist)"} |
  xargs -r0 ls -ld --
```

Note that if any of the globs fails to match a file, in `zsh`, you'll get an error. If you'd rather those globs to expand to nothing, you'd add the `N` glob qualifier to the globs (which enables `nullglob` on a per-glob basis):

```
print -rNC1 -- ${(f)^~"$(<filelist)"}(N) |
  xargs -r0 ls -ld --
```

Adding that `(N)` would also turn all the lines without glob operators into globs allowing to filter out files referenced by path and that don't exist; it would however mean you can't use glob qualifiers in the globs in `filelist` unless you express them as `(#q...)` and enable the `extendedglob` option. Also beware that as qualifiers can run arbitrary code, it's important the contents of the `filelist` file comes from a trusted source.

In other Bourne-like shells, including `bash`, globs that don't match are left as-is, so would be passed literally to `ls` which would likely report an error that the corresponding file doesn't exist.

In `bash`, you could use the `nullglob` option (which it copied from zsh) and handle the case where none of the globs match specially:

```
shopt -s nullglob
IFS=$'\n'
set +o noglob
set -- $(<filelist)
(( $# == 0 )) || printf '%s\0' "$@" | xargs -r0 ls -ld --
```

`bash`, doesn't have any equivalent for `zsh`'s glob qualifiers. To make sure lines without glob operators (such as your `/third/path/example.doc`) are treated as globs and removed if they don't correspond to an actual file, you could add `@()` to the lines (requires `extglob`). That won't work however for line that end in `/` characters. You could however add `@()` to the last non-`/` character and rely on the fact that `/` always exists

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
IFS=$'\n'
set +o noglob
set -- $(LC_ALL=C sed 's|.*[^/]|&@()|' filelist)
(( $# == 0 )) || printf '%s\0' "$@" | xargs -r0 ls -ld --
```

In any case, note that the list of supported glob operators vary greatly with the shell. The only one you're using in your sample (`*`) should be supported by all though.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify your script a little, and call `sh` from `xargs`:

```
cat filelist | xargs -i -- /bin/sh -c 'ls $1' _X_ {}
```

Or let `xargs` read the file itself:

```
xargs -a filelist -i -- /bin/sh -c 'ls $1' _X_ {}
```

Comment: I mean, it is not `--`, but `_` or better `xargs-sh` or so, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/236063). `--` will work, but it might confuse with other uses of `--`

Answer (score 3):

```
while read filepattern
do
    ls $filepattern
done < filelist
```

In this case you want the variable value to be expanded by file globbing, so you have to use the variable without quotes.

The shell will replace `/some/path/*.txt` with the list of matching files.

If you only want to list the file names you don't need `ls`. You can use `echo` instead like `echo $filepattern`.

In contrast to the code above, with quotes you will get the same errors as in the example from the question because the shell will pass the unchanged strings, e.g. `/some/path/*.txt` to `ls`.

```
while read filepattern
do
    ls "$filepattern"
done < filelist
```