# moving specific groups of files to specific group of folders on bash

Tags: linux, bash

For example if I were to move a group of files with the filename of **chapter1_sectionX to a specific folder, say to book/chapter1** and **chapter2_sectionX to book/chapter2** and so on. I am currently using this method which I find it to be inefficient:

```bsh
touch chapter{1,2}_section{1..4}.odf
mkdir -p book/chapter{1,2}
mv chapter1_section* book/chapter1
mv chapter2_section* book/chapter2
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this without using a *for* loop?

Comment: You talk about files containing the word, but you move files based on filename. Please clarify this is what you want.

Comment: Also, what is your issue with `for` loops? This is the perfect application for one.

Comment: I would like to move files based on filename. I'm sry for the confusion caused.

Comment: I'm currently still a noob self learning and haven't read up on for loops yet.

Comment: In that case, it's about time. Hint: Start with `for x in $(seq 1 10); do echo $x; done` and work your way up :)

Comment: Call your chapters chapter01 or chapter001 (in case your memoirs are very long)...

Comment: ic tks for the help

Comment: You are aware that specifying the `mv` _target_ with a wildcard can create problems? Imagine you have directories `book/chapter1` and `book/chapter11` - your shell would expand your command to `mv chapter1<whatever files> book/chapter1 book/chapter11` and all `chapter1` files plus the entire folder `book/chapter1` would end up in `book/chapter11`.

Comment: Tks for the concern, but I do understand the implications of the wildcard character. The format of my filename is chapterX_sectionY.odf. I was simply too lazy to type the rest out and worded my question in a confusing way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, and owing to the simple structure of your file and target directory names, the following `find` command would iterate over all chapter files and move them to a target directory whose name is derived from the filename:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'chapter*_section*.odf' -exec bash -c 'f={}; d="book/${f%_*}"; mv "$f" "$d"' \;
```

This will (implicitly) loop over all files matching `chapter*_section*.odf`, and execute a shell command that derives the target directory name by removing the last `_*` component from the filename, effectively leaving only the `chapterN` part. It will then move the file currently processed to the corresponding subdirectory under `book/`.

**Note**

- The `-maxdepth 1` option is relevant to ensure the operation is only performed on the files in the current directory, and not recursively on those already moved to their target directories once the current directory is processed.
- Embedding the `{}` in a shell command called via `-exec` is [discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/377345) but will work if you don't assume malicious code injection attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Without using a `for` loop?  You can use the perl `rename` utility (also known as `prename`, or `file-rename` or `perl-rename` on some distros) to create the subdirectories and rename the files into them.  For example:

```bsh
$ rename -v 'BEGIN{mkdir "book"};
             if (m/chapter(\d+)/) {
               my $d="book/chapter$1";
               mkdir $d;
               $_ = "$d/$_"
             }' *
chapter1.txt renamed as book/chapter1/chapter1.txt
chapter2.txt renamed as book/chapter2/chapter2.txt
chapter3.txt renamed as book/chapter3/chapter3.txt
chapter4.txt renamed as book/chapter4/chapter4.txt
chapter5.txt renamed as book/chapter5/chapter5.txt
```

English summary of the script:

If the current filename (`$_`) matches the regex `chapter(\d+)` then extract the chapter number from the filename (i.e. `$1`, which is the first and only capture group in the regex, the `(\d+)`), create a directory for the chapter, and then rename the current file into the directory.

Non-matching filenames are ignored.

perl `rename` only attempts to rename a file if the rename script changes the value of `$_`.   It also refuses to overwrite an existing file unless you force it to with the `-f` option.

perl rename allows you to use **any** perl code within the rename script (but note that it the `use strict` pragma is in force so you need to declare your variables).  If the code changes `$_`, the file will be renamed.  If not, it won't.

Note that it's good practice to do a dry-run first with the `-n` option to make sure that rename is going to do what you want it to (recovering from a bad bulk rename can be a major PITA).  `-n` doesn't rename any files, it just shows what it **would** do.  Replace the `-n` with `-v` (as I have above) to get verbose output, or just remove the `-n` for silent operation.

Comment: Appreciate the response but I was hoping that there was some method of implementing my code above using the built in utilities. I had this weird idea after learning brace expansion and was fascinated by its combining and nesting capabilites. Guess I was asking for the impossible

Comment: that's OK.  I cheated.  With perl `rename`, there's an implicit loop over all the filenames, with `$_` being set to the current filename for each iteration of the loop.    But unless you rename each filename manually, the only way to do this *is* with a loop of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

I find the `mmv` utility handy for stuff like this:

```
$ mmv -v 'chapter*_section*.odf' 'book/chapter#1/'
chapter1_section1.odf -> book/chapter1/chapter1_section1.odf : done
chapter1_section2.odf -> book/chapter1/chapter1_section2.odf : done
chapter1_section3.odf -> book/chapter1/chapter1_section3.odf : done
chapter1_section4.odf -> book/chapter1/chapter1_section4.odf : done
chapter2_section1.odf -> book/chapter2/chapter2_section1.odf : done
chapter2_section2.odf -> book/chapter2/chapter2_section2.odf : done
chapter2_section3.odf -> book/chapter2/chapter2_section3.odf : done
chapter2_section4.odf -> book/chapter2/chapter2_section4.odf : done
```

giving

```
$ tree book
book
├── chapter1
│   ├── chapter1_section1.odf
│   ├── chapter1_section2.odf
│   ├── chapter1_section3.odf
│   └── chapter1_section4.odf
└── chapter2
    ├── chapter2_section1.odf
    ├── chapter2_section2.odf
    ├── chapter2_section3.odf
    └── chapter2_section4.odf

2 directories, 8 files
```