# No output: busybox find . -exec sh -c ' readlink -f "$1" | tail -n +2 ' sh {} \;

Tags: linux, find, tail, busybox, stdin

I got access to only Busybox 1.31.1

I originally wanted to remove the current working directory of my output (the single dot).

Example:

```
/prueba$ ls
uno dos tres
```

When I:

```
$ busybox find .
.
./uno
./dos
./tres
```

That's easily done with either:

```
busybox find . -not -path .
busybox find . -mindepth 1
```

Now, what I tried before is:

```
busybox find . -exec sh -c ' readlink -f "$1" | tail -n +2 ' sh {} \;
```

Which prints nothing. If verbose output is activated:

```
==> standard input <==
==> standard input <==
==> standard input <==
==> standard input <==
==> standard input <==
```

Completely different output if the line address is one:

```
busybox find . -exec sh -c ' readlink -f "$1" | tail -n +1 ' sh {} \;
```

```
==> standard input <==
/tmp/prueba
==> standard input <==
/tmp/prueba/tres
==> standard input <==
/tmp/prueba/dos
==> standard input <==
/tmp/prueba/uno
```

What's going on?

Comment: I suppose you mean `-mindepth 1`, not `-maxdepth 1`, since the `.` given on the command line is at depth 0. But is there a particular reason to use `tail` and not the two ways you already have for removing `.` from the output of `find`?

Comment: @ilkkachu Hello. Yes, I'll will edit my post. No, there is no particular reason to use  tail  I was using it due to ignorance, I tought that was the way to go, but after knowing that  find  can do it by itself I was just curious why I wasn't getting the output I wanted.

Comment: yep, just wondering. Namely, `find . -not -path . -exec ...` should work too.

Comment: I was told `-not` is non-standard, better to use `!` which is standard complaint. Any literature work you can recommend to know the "right" way?

Comment: right, `!` is the standard one. Though just based on the man pages, the GNU, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Busybox versions support `-not` too. (Plus `-and` and `-or` which are similarly nonstandard variants of `-a` and `-o`.) In this case, the [GNU manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) even mentions those are not POSIX compliant. The [specification is online](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html) too, but as you might guess with a standard, it's not always the most fluent read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
-exec some command with parms {} \;
```

invokes the command once for each file. In your case the `readlink` outputs one line of output, and then your `tail -n +2` strips off the first line, leaving you with nothing. If you use `tail -n +1` this is just a verbose way of saying `cat`, to copy the input to output.

If you rewrite it so the `tail -n +2` is outside the implicit loop like this

```
busybox find . -exec sh -c ' readlink -f "$1" ' sh {} \; | tail -n +2
```

you will get your expected result.

You can make the command more efficient by batching the command execution.

```
busybox find . -exec readlink -f -- {} + | tail -n +2
```

This requires the command you want to run taking multiple files. The `+` rather than the `\;` makes find run the command many fewer times as it runs the command only when it has a full buffer of filenames rather than once per file. Obviously I have also removed the unneeded `sh` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm amazed on how quickly a clear and well done explanation can be provided within minutes. Internet is awesome, you guys are awesome!

About the unneeded  sh  . I did because I tend to work with multiple files with non ASCII names and with spaces as well. So I followed this advise, just to be on the safe side:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010

Comment: The point about spaces and other 'interesting' characters in names is that they are a problem for the shell. Remove the extra shell and the issue with spaces goes away. I added an extra `--` to the answer so filenames like `-m` don't cause problems.

Comment: What `--` does? Is it for `find` or for `readlink`?

Comment: `--` is a standard convention to indicate the end of options. This allows you to distinguish between a file called `-i` and an option `-i`. In this case it is for readlink.

Comment: Strictly speaking, while it's good practice to use `--` and never harms, here it's not strictly necessary as all arguments will start with `./`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Totally agree. The problem only arises if `.` is replaced with a list of files. The most likely way that an unsuspecting person would generate such a list is with filename expansion. I haven't seen the advice recently but at one time there was a suggestion to have a file called `-i` so if you typed `rm *` and the filename came first or your version of argument parsing sorted `options` to the front you would get some warning that you were about to delete more than you expected.

Comment: @icarus, yes, there's (or at least was) such a `-i` file in the source tarball of `bash` for that reason. Note that `--` is necessary with `-execdir` with some implementations of `find`.