# No batch processing when: busybox find . -exec

Tags: find, mv, unicode, busybox

I have access to only busybox.

I have a folder, like this:

```
prueba/$: ls
./uno
./dos
./tres
```

Each two subdirectories (uno, dos) have many files (with spaces in their names and non-ASCII characters) and I want to move them over to the other subdirectory (tres).

So I did this (escaping characters just because, making sure I don't do redundancy when copying and using yes just to replace any file already in directory [tres] I have had issues with mv -f before):

```
prueba/$: busybox find . -type f -not \( -path . -o -path ./tres \) -exec sh -c ' yes | mv "$1" ./tres ' sh {} \+
```

But it moves just the first file it finds and then exits.

But if I run:

```
prueba/$: busybox find . -type f -not \( -path . -o -path ./tres \) -exec sh -c ' yes | mv "$1" ./tres ' sh {} \;
```

I got what I expected. All files are moved from subdirectories "uno" and "dos" onto subdirecty "tres".

What is the internal mechanism that is activated when `;` [implicit loop] and `+` [implicit batch processing] are in place?

What's wrong with the first command line (the one with `+`)?

The following is out of the question:

```
mv -f ./uno/* ./dos/* ./tres/
```

I'm doing some automated work that will require me to just run a one-liner and be done with the job. Plus, is a boring solution.

Edit:

The reason behind `find . -exec sh -c 'CMD "$1"' sh {} \;`

[Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely/156010#156010)

Comment: Thank you. What will be the way to go? Appending `+` or using `$@`  as a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
find uno/ dos/ -type f -exec sh -c 'exec mv -f "$@" tres/' sh {} +
```

The problems with your code:

- `find . -not -path ./tres` does exclude `./tres`, but not `./tres/any-file-in-it`
- `-exec sh 'mv "$1" tres' sh {} +` calls `sh` with as many files as possible as arguments, but you're only moving the first (`$1`). `"$@"` expands to *all* the positional arguments as separate arguments, as if you had written `"$1" "$2" "$3" ... "$last"`.
- Note the `!` as standard alternative to non-standard `-not`
- Note that `+` is not a special character in any shell. It doesn't need to be quoted.
- Note the `-f` option of `mv` to avoid prompting in the first place so you don't need `yes`. If you still wanted to use `yes`, you could just do `yes | find ... -exec sh -c 'exec mv ...`, as `sh` and `mv` will inherit `find`'s stdin and read the `y`s from there.
- With the `mv` implementation from GNU coreutils and recent versions of `busybox`, you can avoid the `sh` invocation by using `find ... -exec mv -ft tres {} +`.

If you wanted to move the files from any directory (recursively) except those in `./tres` and excluding files in the current directory, you'd need:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -path ./tres -prune -o \
                -path './*/*' -type f -exec sh -c 'exec mv -f "$@" tres/' sh {} +
```

It's the `-prune` above that tells `find` not to look for files inside `./tres`, and for other files, `-path './*/*'` (in combination with `LC_ALL=C` so `*` matches any string of bytes, not just characters) restricts to files whose path contains at least one `/` after the leading `./`, so excluding files in the current directory.

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
mv -f -- (^tres)/**/*(D.) tres/
```

Though beware that if there are symlinks to directories in the current directory, they  will be followed. It  could also fail if your system's limit on the number and size of arguments is reached (see `zargs` to work around it).

Contrary to `find`, `zsh` globs do sort the list of files, so if there are several files with the same name, which one will end up in `./tres` will be more deterministic (that'll be the one whose path sorts last though beware `uno` comes after `dos` as the order is lexical¹; **all the other ones will be lost**)

---

<sup>¹ you can add the `n` glob qualifier to get a numerical order, but that's only for sequences of digits (for `dir2` to come before `dir10` for instance), `uno` will still sort after `dos`)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the heads up in regards simlinks and files already in `./tres` I did not take that into account. I tried your suggestion `find . -path ./tres -prune -o -path './*/*'` just to check how the command works. For now is just printing `./tres`. How do I implement `!` if (let's say) I want to exclude a file in `./dos` and how exactly are options being implement by find, I do not fully understand which directory is the one being affected by each option `-path ./tres -prune -o -path './*/*'` I'm specially confused by `-path './*/*'` what's that for?

Comment: @abacox. Don't just remove the `-exec` to test. You need to replace it with `-print`. See also [\`find\` with multiple \`-name\` and \`-exec\` executes only the last matches of \`-name\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191)

Comment: Did it, with or without `-print` there is no output, actually. I'm getting a result only if `find . -path ./tres -prune -print` is entered (same as before `-print` doesn't make a difference).

Comment: @abacox, you mean `LC_ALL=C busybox find . -path ./tres -prune -o -path './*/*' -type f -print` outputs nothing? Then that would mean there is no regular files in any subdirectory of `.` except in `./tres`, presumably because they've been moved there already.

Comment: When I test my test enviroment is the same, so `./tres` was with nothing and the other folders with dummy files. I tought `LC_ALL=C` was already explicit in my `sh` shell (I'm in a very bare bones system). Interesting, why `LC_ALL=C` determines if the output gets printed? (Now I got output, but it's weird. With `LC_ALL=C` if `-print` is present I do get the expected result but without `-print`, `./tres` is included).

Comment: `-path './*/*'` could fail to match on file paths that can't be decoded as text (you mentioned your filenames have non-ASCII characters). Without a `-print`, there is an implicit `-print`, but that's for the files that match the whole expression, not just the ones that match on the right side of the `-o`. See the link I gave earlier.

Comment: Thank you. For now, my test folders doesn't have any special character in their filenames, they have as a name just 1 word, no spaces, everything within ASCII, no points, etc.