# Loop through subdirectories to get files and do something on them

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying to loop through the folders to get the files and do something on them, with output redirected to a text file with the same name as the file. I tried using 'find' -

```
cd /filepath/orig/v1

for dir in $(find . -type d); do
  cd $dir
  for subdir in $(find . -type d); do
          cd $subdir
          for file in `ls`; do
                  echo $file
                  touch $file.txt
                  cdo info $file > $file.txt
          done
  done
done
```

But this does not work. The directory structure is like - /filepath/orig/v1/level1/level2/file.nc but subdirectories can have more than two levels.

Comment: The first `for dir in $(find . -type d); do` would already find every directory on all levels of the tree. Do you need to find the directories here, or is it enough to process all the _files_ individually?

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Either use loops or use find, don't do both.  Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dumped 'find' because I had trouble understanding its concept, but seems like this worked -

```
orig_dir='/filepath/orig/v1'

for entry in "$orig_dir"/*/*; do
    cd "$entry"
    x=`ls *.nc`
    echo "$x"
    name=`basename $x .nc`
    cdo info "$x" > new_path/"$name".txt
    
done
```

Comment: [Quote properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Answer (score 2):

Loops are unnecessary for this.  Find will do it all.

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.txt' -print -exec sh -c 'cdo info {} > {}.txt' \;
```

Note that this will clobber existing .txt files and you might want to use a more specific filename filter than "not *.txt"

Comment: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Comment: This does not control the depth on which the files will be found.

Comment: If you want to control depth, find has a `-depth` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed directory structure of two levels:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for pathname in /filepath/orig/v1/*/*; do
    [[ $pathname == *.txt ]] && continue

    printf 'Processing "%s"\n' "$pathname" >&2
    
    cdo info "$pathname" >"$pathname.txt"
done
```

This first enables the `dotglob` and `nullglob` shell options.  These shell options allows globbing patterns to match hidden names (`dotglob`) and will ensure that patterns that are *not* matched are removed completely (`nullglob`; this means the loop would not run a single iteration if `/filepath/orig/v1/*/*` does not match any names).

Any name in our loop that already ends with `.txt` is skipped, and the rest is processed with `cdo info` to generate a `.txt` file (note that I don't know what `cdo info` actually does).  Note that there is no need to `touch` the filename first as the file would be created by virtue of redirecting into it.

Related:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

---

If you know you will only process files with names ending in `.nc`:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for pathname in /filepath/orig/v1/*/*.nc; do
    printf 'Processing "%s"\n' "$pathname" >&2
    cdo info "$pathname" >"$pathname.txt"
done
```

---

If you want to process all files with names ending in `.nc` *anywhere* beneath `/filepath/orig/v1`:

```bsh
find /filepath/orig/v1 -type f -name '*.nc' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "Processing \"%s\"\n" "$pathname" >&2
        cdo info "$pathname" >"$pathname.txt"
    done' sh {} +
```

This calls a short in-line script for batches of found regular files with names ending in `.nc`.

You could also use `/filepath/orig/v1/*/` as the search path with `find` to only search the subdirectories of `/filepath/orig/v1` and not `/filepath/orig/v1` itself.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel:

```
doit() {
  dir="$1"
  file="$2"
  cd "$dir"
  echo "$file"
  touch "$file".txt
  cdo info "$file" > "$file".txt
}
export -f doit
# 2 level only
printf "%s\0" */*/* | parallel -0 doit {//} {/}
# any level
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 doit {//} {/}
```

If you do not need the `echo`, `touch`, and if `cdo` can work on full path it can be shorter:

```
# 2 level only
printf "%s\0" */*/* | parallel -0 'cdo info {} > {}.txt'
# any level
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 'cdo info {} > {}.txt'
```

Contrary to `xargs'` shell code, `{}` is safe here.

If you want `foo.nc` to result in `foo.txt`:

```
# 2 level only
printf "%s\0" */*/*.nc | parallel -0 'cdo info {} > {.}.txt'
# any level
find . -type f -name '*.nc' -print0 | parallel -0 'cdo info {} > {.}.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU or BSD `find`, you can use the `-execdir` option.  It's the same as `-exec` except that it changes into the directory containing the file(s) first (and if you're using `+` instead of `;` to terminate the -execdir, it batches up the files in the same dir to minimise to minimise the amount of forking per directory).  e.g.

```
find . -type f -execdir \
  sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s\n" "$f" ; cdo info "$f" > "$f.txt"; done' sh {} +
```

Notes:

1. `for f; do` is the same as `for f in "$@"; do`
2. The **first** arg to the `sh -c '...'` command is `sh`.  That's the name that will be used in the process table for the `sh -c` being executed by `-exec` or `-execdir` - i.e. `$0`. You can use any arbitrary name you like there - `sh` or `find-sh` are commonly used.  If it's not there, then the shell script **will not see** the first filename found by `find`.  This is specific to `sh -c` (and some other commands, usually script interpreters, like `bash -c`), it is **not** required for most commands that you might want to run with `find -exec` or `-execdir` (e.g. `grep` and `sed` don't need it)
3. This uses `-type f` because, even though we want find to `cd` into the directory containing files, we only want to process regular files, not directories (or sockets, named pipes, symlinks, etc).  If you want to process regular files and symlinks, use either find's `-L` option or `\( -type f -o -type l \)`.  Note that `-L` will follow symlinks to directories **outside** of your search tree, which is not usually what you want.

   If using `\( -type f -o -type l \)`. the embedded `sh -c` script should check each argument to be sure that it (e.g. `"$f"` in my examples) is either a regular file or a symlink pointing to a regular file (`test -f` will do this for both because, as documented in `help test` and `man test`, "Except for -h and -L, all FILE-related tests dereference symbolic links.").

   ```
   find . \( -type f -o -type l \) -execdir \
     sh -c 'for f; do
              printf "%s\n" "$f"
              [ -f "$f" ] && cdo info "$f" > "$f.txt"
            done' sh {} +
   ```
4. All variable expansions in the `sh -c` script are double-quoted.  As they should be (See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for why)

---

If you need to limit the search depth, you can use the `-maxdepth` option.  e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -execdir \
  sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s\n" "$f" ; cdo info "$f" > "$f.txt"; done' sh {} +
```

find also has related options like `-d` or `-depth`, and `-mindepth` for controlling how it traverses a directory tree.

---

PS: I don't know what the `cdo` command does or what arguments it takes but if it supports using `--` to mark the end of options and the start of filename args, you should include it in the command, otherwise filenames beginning with `-` may be treated as options to `cdo`.  e.g.

```
find . -type f -execdir \
  sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s\n" "$f" ; cdo info -- "$f" > "$f.txt"; done' sh {} +
```

This is (part of) the reason why I used `printf` instead of `echo`.  See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)