# For all zips, and unzip in working directory and maintains its structure

Tags: directory, zip, recursive, gunzip

With this command

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip '{}' ';'
```

we find all zip files under . (directory), then unzip them into the current working directory,
**However,**  the structure is gone.

```
/backUp/pic1/1-1.zip
/backUp/pic1/1-2.zip
/backUp/pic2/2-1.zip
/backUp/pic2/2-2.zip
/backUp/pic3/3-1.zip
/backUp/pic3/3-2.zip
/backUp/pic3/3-3.zip

Current command result:
/new/1-1
/new/1-2
/new/2-1
/new/2-2
/new/3-1
/new/3-2
/new/3-3





desired  result  
/new/pic1/1-1 
/new/pic1/1-2 
/new/pic2/2-1
/new/pic2/2-2
/new/pic3/3-1
/new/pic3/3-2
/new/pic3/3-3
```

Asked here, but the code doesn't work out
[What should dirname and basename be in this command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691527/what-should-dirname-and-basename-be-in-this-command)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should dirname and basename be in this command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691527/what-should-dirname-and-basename-be-in-this-command)

Comment: Not really. since the code didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with the `-execdir` argument instead of `-exec`.

`-execdir` will run the command in the directory it has found the files in, instead of your current working directory

Example:

`find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip {} \;`

While this is not exactly what you've asked for, you could add a few steps to get to the desired result:

```
mkdir new
cp -a backUP/* new/
#run unzip operation
cd new
find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip {} \;
#remove all .zip files
find . -name '*.zip' -exec rm {} \;
```