# "xargs -I" not working for child command

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

`xargs -I` not working for child command

Example:

```bash
# Not working
ls ....  | xargs -n 1 -I % sh -c  "cmd $(cmd2 % )"
# working
ls ....  | xargs -n 1 -I % sh -c  "cmd % "
```

Is there any solution for how to substitute inside child class?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the shell would expand the command substitution in the double-quoted string argument *before `xargs` is even started*, meaning the shell would run `cmd2` with the literal argument `%` to calculate the last argument for `xargs`.

Your second example command does not have this issue as the shell code argument at the end does not contain any expansions that the calling shell would need to process before starting `xargs`.

You would solve this in the first command by simply single-quoting the argument instead of double-quoting it.

However, there are good reasons why parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea.  Since you embed the `%` placeholder in shell code that will be executed by `sh -c`, you would also have real issues if any filename contained quoting or globbing characters or expansions like `$(...)` or any other expansions.  In this case, it would be safer to use an ordinary shell loop:

```bash
for name in ...; do cmd "$(cmd2 "$name")"; done
```

or, arguably more readable,

```bash
for name in ...; do
    cmd "$(cmd2 "$name")"
done
```

... where `...` is a pattern that matches the names you are interested in.

---

See also:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Also related (embedding `%` in shell code with `xargs` has the same issues as embedding `{}` in shell code with `find`):

- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely)