# Find files matching one pattern, but not another, using grep, awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find, pattern-matching

I need to locate `.php` and `.pl` files that do not contain one string (e.g. `aaa`), but do contain another (e.g. `bbb`).

I'm currently using this command:

```
find /path/ \( -iname '*.php*' -or -name '*.pl*' \) -exec sh -c 'grep -l -v "aaa" {} | grep -l "bbb" {}' \; > resulttofile
```

It's about half a million files to search, so I'm wondering,

- If my command works correctly - some eye sampling gives positive result,
- If it's possible to become faster (it currently takes about 2min on a VM, but more files will be added) using some other form, or `awk` or `sed` instead of `grep` - or perhaps just one combined `grep` instead of two.

---

The system is a Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: Please remember to _always_ tell us your operating system. Especially for questions like this since different systems will have different implementations of the basic tools like `grep` or `find`.

Comment: Don’t change it now, but “not `aaa` but `bbb`” is confusing —  “`aaa` but not `bbb`” would be clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your command doesn’t work correctly: the first `grep` will list any file which contains a line not matching `"aaa"`, and the second `grep` will ignore the first’s output since it’s given its own file to process — so you’ll get a list of files matching `"bbb"`, regardless of whether they contain `"aaa"` or not. You’d need to ask `grep` to only list a file if it doesn’t contain any line matching `"aaa"` (`grep -L`), and use `xargs` to process the resulting list of files and only feed that to the second `grep` (or make the second `grep` conditional on the result of the first one).

On top of that, it would work only as long as the file names that `find` lists don’t cause problems for the shell — notably, including `{}` directly in the command given to `sh -c` means that file names can end up being interpreted as shell commands (see [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/86440) for details).

The following will require fewer `grep` invocations and is safer, assuming you’re using GNU `grep`:

```
find /path/ \( -iname '*.php*' -o -name '*.pl*' \) -exec grep -LZ aaa {} + |
  xargs -r0 grep -l bbb
```

The **`-or`** operator is a GNU extension to `find`. 
Use **`-o`** for portability.

Answer (score 5):

Untested but this should do what I think you want, using GNU awk for `nextfile` and `ENDFILE`

```
find /path/ \( -iname '*.php*' -or -name '*.pl*' \) -exec awk '
    /aaa/{a=1} /bbb/{b=1} a&&b{nextfile} ENDFILE{if (b && !a) print FILENAME; a=b=0}
' {} + > resulttofile
```

The above only calls awk once on multiple files at a time so should be efficient.

The above is how to generally match multiple patterns in a file and then evaluate the results of the combination of matches once the file has been fully read but as [@G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80216/g-man-says-reinstate-monica) mentioned in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744320/find-files-matching-one-pattern-but-not-another-using-grep-awk-or-sed/744355?noredirect=1#comment1415658_744355) you could make it more efficient in this specific case by stopping reading the current file if/when `aaa` matches since the success criteria is for `aaa` not to be present:

```
/aaa/{a=1; nextfile} /bbb/{b=1} ENDFILE{if (b && !a) print FILENAME; a=b=0}
```

Comment: Doesn't `-exec`call the command *once* per filename? If the `awk`is ready to process multiple filenames, why not use `-print0` and `| xargs -0 ...`?

Comment: @Quasímodo Must be an extension younger than I ;-)

Comment: Why not `/aaa/{a=1; nextfile} /bbb/{b=1}  ENDFILE{if (b && !a) print FILENAME; a=b=0}`?  Or just `/aaa/{b=0; nextfile} /bbb/{b=1}  ENDFILE{if (b) print FILENAME; b=0}`?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' good point, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may chain multiple -exec directives (or other ones) together with one find command:

```
find /path \( -iname '*.php*' -or -name '*.pl*' \) -exec grep -q "bbb" {} ";" \
     -exec grep -L "aaa" {} ";" > resulttofile
```

(The linebreak is only to fit the layout of SE).